# A CSharpish String.Format formatting helper

Tags: strings, vba, formatting, vb6

A while ago I implemented .net's `string.Format()` method in VB6; it works amazingly well, but I'm sure there has to be a way to make it more efficient.

I'll start by listing a simple class called `EscapeSequence`:

```
Private Type tEscapeSequence
    EscapeString As String
    ReplacementString As String
End Type

Private this As tEscapeSequence
Option Explicit

Public Property Get EscapeString() As String
    EscapeString = this.EscapeString
End Property

Friend Property Let EscapeString(value As String)
    this.EscapeString = value
End Property

Public Property Get ReplacementString() As String
    ReplacementString = this.ReplacementString
End Property

Friend Property Let ReplacementString(value As String)
    this.ReplacementString = value
End Property

'Lord I wish VB6 had constructors!
Public Function Create(escape As String, replacement As String) As EscapeSequence
    Dim result As New EscapeSequence
    result.EscapeString = escape
    result.ReplacementString = replacement
    Set Create = result
End Function
```

...and the actual `StringFormat` function - there's a global variable `PADDING_CHAR` involved, which I'd love to find a way to specify and de-globalize:

```
Public Function StringFormat(format_string As String, ParamArray values()) As String
'VB6 implementation of .net String.Format(), slightly customized.

        Dim return_value As String
        Dim values_count As Integer

        'some error-handling constants:
        Const ERR_FORMAT_EXCEPTION As Long = vbObjectError Or 9001
        Const ERR_ARGUMENT_NULL_EXCEPTION As Long = vbObjectError Or 9002
        Const ERR_ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION As Long = vbObjectError Or 9003
        Const ERR_SOURCE As String = "StringFormat"
        Const ERR_MSG_INVALID_FORMAT_STRING As String = "Invalid format string."
        Const ERR_MSG_FORMAT_EXCEPTION As String = "The number indicating an argument to format is less than zero, or greater than or equal to the length of the args array."
        Const ERR_MSG_NUMBER_ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION As String = "Invalid number argument."

        'use SPACE as default padding character
        If PADDING_CHAR = vbNullString Then PADDING_CHAR = Chr$(32)

        'figure out number of passed values:
        values_count = UBound(values) + 1

        Dim regex As RegExp
        Dim matches As MatchCollection
        Dim thisMatch As Match
        Dim thisString As String
        Dim thisFormat As String

        Dim useLiteral As Boolean 'when format_string starts with "@", escapes are not replaced (string is treated as a literal string with placeholders)
        Dim escapeHex As Boolean 'indicates whether HEX specifier "0x" is to be escaped or not

        'validate string_format:
        Set regex = New RegExp
        regex.pattern = "{({{)*(\w+)(,-?\d+)?(:[^}]+)?}(}})*"
        regex.IgnoreCase = True
        regex.Global = True
        Set matches = regex.Execute(format_string)

        'determine if values_count matches number of unique regex matches:
        Dim uniqueCount As Integer
        Dim tmpCSV As String
        For Each thisMatch In matches
            If Not StringContains(tmpCSV, thisMatch.SubMatches(1)) Then
                uniqueCount = uniqueCount + 1
                tmpCSV = tmpCSV & thisMatch.SubMatches(1) & ","
            End If
        Next

        'unique indices count must match values_count:
        If matches.Count > 0 And uniqueCount <> values_count Then
            Err.Raise ERR_FORMAT_EXCEPTION, _
            ERR_SOURCE, ERR_MSG_FORMAT_EXCEPTION
        End If

        useLiteral = StringStartsWith("@", format_string)
        If useLiteral Then format_string = Right(format_string, Len(format_string) - 1) 'remove the "@" literal specifier

        If Not useLiteral And StringContains(format_string, "\\") Then _
            format_string = Replace(format_string, "\\", Chr$(27))

        If matches.Count = 0 And format_string <> vbNullString And UBound(values) = -1 Then
        'only format_string was specified: skip to checking escape sequences:
            return_value = format_string
            GoTo checkEscapes
        ElseIf UBound(values) = -1 And matches.Count > 0 Then
            Err.Raise ERR_ARGUMENT_NULL_EXCEPTION, _
                ERR_SOURCE, ERR_MSG_FORMAT_EXCEPTION
        End If

        return_value = format_string

        'dissect format_string:

        Dim i As Integer, v As String, p As String 'i: iterator; v: value; p: placeholder
        Dim alignmentGroup As String, alignmentSpecifier As String
        Dim formattedValue As String, alignmentPadding As Integer

        'iterate regex matches (each match is a placeholder):
        For i = 0 To matches.Count - 1

            'get the placeholder specified index:
            Set thisMatch = matches(i)
            p = thisMatch.SubMatches(1)

            'if specified index (0-based) > uniqueCount (1-based), something's wrong:
            If p > uniqueCount - 1 Then
                Err.Raise ERR_FORMAT_EXCEPTION, _
                ERR_SOURCE, ERR_MSG_FORMAT_EXCEPTION
            End If
            v = values(p)

            'get the alignment specifier if it is specified:
            alignmentGroup = thisMatch.SubMatches(2)
            If alignmentGroup <> vbNullString Then _
                alignmentSpecifier = Right$(alignmentGroup, LenB(alignmentGroup) / 2 - 1)


            'get the format specifier if it is specified:
            thisString = thisMatch.value
            If StringContains(thisString, ":") Then

                Dim formatGroup As String, precisionSpecifier As Integer
                Dim formatSpecifier As String, precisionString As String

                'get the string between ":" and "}":
                formatGroup = mId$(thisString, InStr(1, thisString, ":") + 1, (LenB(thisString) / 2) - 2)
                formatGroup = Left$(formatGroup, LenB(formatGroup) / 2 - 1)

                precisionString = Right$(formatGroup, LenB(formatGroup) / 2 - 1)
                formatSpecifier = mId$(thisString, InStr(1, thisString, ":") + 1, 1)

                'applicable formatting depends on the type of the value (yes, GOTO!!):
                If TypeName(values(p)) = "Date" Then GoTo DateTimeFormatSpecifiers
                If v = vbNullString Then GoTo ApplyStringFormat

NumberFormatSpecifiers:
                If precisionString <> vbNullString And Not IsNumeric(precisionString) Then
                    Err.Raise ERR_FORMAT_EXCEPTION, _
                        ERR_SOURCE, ERR_MSG_INVALID_FORMAT_STRING
                End If

                If Not IsNumeric(v) Then
                    Err.Raise ERR_ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION, _
                        ERR_SOURCE, ERR_MSG_NUMBER_ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION
                End If

                If precisionString = vbNullString Then precisionString = 0

                Select Case formatSpecifier

                    Case "C", "c" 'CURRENCY format, formats string as currency.
                    'Precision specifier determines number of decimal digits.
                    'This implementation ignores regional settings
                    '(hard-coded group separator, decimal separator and currency sign).

                    precisionSpecifier = CInt(precisionString)
                    thisFormat = "#,##0.$"

                    If LenB(formatGroup) > 2 And precisionSpecifier > 0 Then
                        'if a non-zero precision is specified...
                        thisFormat = _
                        Replace$(thisFormat, ".", "." & String$(precisionString, Chr$(48)))
                    Else
                        thisFormat = CURRENCY_FORMAT
                    End If


                    Case "D", "d" 'DECIMAL format, formats string as integer number.
                    'Precision specifier determines number of digits in returned string.


                    precisionSpecifier = CInt(precisionString)
                    thisFormat = "0"
                    thisFormat = Right$(String$(precisionSpecifier, "0") & thisFormat, _
                        IIf(precisionSpecifier = 0, Len(thisFormat), precisionSpecifier))


                    Case "E", "e" 'EXPONENTIAL NOTATION format (aka "Scientific Notation")
                    'Precision specifier determines number of decimals in returned string.
                    'This implementation ignores regional settings'
                    '(hard-coded decimal separator).


                    precisionSpecifier = CInt(precisionString)
                    thisFormat = "0.00000#" & formatSpecifier & "-#" 'defaults to 6 decimals

                    If LenB(formatGroup) > 2 And precisionSpecifier > 0 Then
                        'if a non-zero precision is specified...
                        thisFormat = "0." & String$(precisionSpecifier - 1, Chr$(48)) & "#" & formatSpecifier & "-#"

                    ElseIf LenB(formatGroup) > 2 And precisionSpecifier = 0 Then
                        Err.Raise ERR_FORMAT_EXCEPTION, _
                            ERR_SOURCE, ERR_MSG_INVALID_FORMAT_STRING
                    End If


                    Case "F", "f" 'FIXED-POINT format
                    'Precision specifier determines number of decimals in returned string.
                    'This implementation ignores regional settings'
                    '(hard-coded decimal separator).

                    precisionSpecifier = CInt(precisionString)
                    thisFormat = "0"
                    If LenB(formatGroup) > 2 And precisionSpecifier > 0 Then
                        'if a non-zero precision is specified...
                        thisFormat = (thisFormat & ".") & String$(precisionSpecifier, Chr$(48))
                    Else
                        'no precision specified - default to 2 decimals:
                        thisFormat = "0.00"
                    End If


                    Case "G", "g" 'GENERAL format (recursive)
                    'returns the shortest of either FIXED-POINT or SCIENTIFIC formats in case of a Double.
                    'returns DECIMAL format in case of a Integer or Long.

                    Dim eNotation As String, ePower As Integer, specifier As String
                    precisionSpecifier = IIf(CInt(precisionString) > 0, CInt(precisionString), _
                        IIf(StringContains(v, "."), Len(v) - InStr(1, v, "."), 0))

                    'track character case of formatSpecifier:
                    specifier = IIf(formatSpecifier = "G", "D", "d")

                    If TypeName(values(p)) = "Integer" Or TypeName(values(p)) = "Long" Then
                        'Integer types: use {0:D} (recursive call):
                        formattedValue = StringFormat("{0:" & specifier & "}", values(p))

                    ElseIf TypeName(values(p)) = "Double" Then
                        'Non-integer types: use {0:E}
                        specifier = IIf(formatSpecifier = "G", "E", "e")

                        'evaluate the exponential notation value (recursive call):
                        eNotation = StringFormat("{0:" & specifier & "}", v)

                        'get the power of eNotation:
                        ePower = mId$(eNotation, InStr(1, UCase$(eNotation), "E-") + 1, Len(eNotation) - InStr(1, UCase$(eNotation), "E-"))

                        If ePower > -5 And Abs(ePower) < precisionSpecifier Then
                            'use {0:F} when ePower > -5 and abs(ePower) < precisionSpecifier:
                            'evaluate the floating-point value (recursive call):
                             specifier = IIf(formatSpecifier = "G", "F", "f")
                             formattedValue = StringFormat("{0:" & formatSpecifier & _
                                 IIf(precisionSpecifier <> 0, precisionString, vbNullString) & "}", values(p))
                        Else
                            'fallback to {0:E} if previous rule didn't apply:
                            formattedValue = eNotation
                        End If

                    End If

                    GoTo AlignFormattedValue 'Skip the "ApplyStringFormat" step, it's applied already.


                    Case "N", "n" 'NUMERIC format, formats string as an integer or decimal number.
                    'Precision specifier determines number of decimal digits.
                    'This implementation ignores regional settings'
                    '(hard-coded group and decimal separators).

                    precisionSpecifier = CInt(precisionString)
                    If LenB(formatGroup) > 2 And precisionSpecifier > 0 Then
                        'if a non-zero precision is specified...
                        thisFormat = "#,##0"
                        thisFormat = (thisFormat & ".") & String$(precisionSpecifier, Chr$(48))

                    Else 'only the "D" is specified
                        thisFormat = "#,##0"
                    End If


                    Case "P", "p" 'PERCENT format. Formats string as a percentage.
                    'Value is multiplied by 100 and displayed with a percent symbol.
                    'Precision specifier determines number of decimal digits.

                    thisFormat = "#,##0%"
                    precisionSpecifier = CInt(precisionString)
                    If LenB(formatGroup) > 2 And precisionSpecifier > 0 Then
                        'if a non-zero precision is specified...
                        thisFormat = "#,##0"
                        thisFormat = (thisFormat & ".") & String$(precisionSpecifier, Chr$(48))

                    Else 'only the "P" is specified
                        thisFormat = "#,##0"
                    End If

                    'Append the percentage sign to the format string:
                    thisFormat = thisFormat & "%"


                    Case "R", "r" 'ROUND-TRIP format (a string that can round-trip to an identical number)
                    'example: ?StringFormat("{0:R}", 0.0000000001141596325677345362656)
                    '         ...returns "0.000000000114159632567735"

                    'convert value to a Double (chop off overflow digits):
                    v = CDbl(v)


                    Case "X", "x" 'HEX format. Formats a string as a Hexadecimal value.
                    'Precision specifier determines number of total digits.
                    'Returned string is prefixed with "&H" to specify Hex.

                    v = Hex(v)
                    precisionSpecifier = CInt(precisionString)

                    If LenB(precisionString) > 0 Then 'precision here stands for left padding
                        v = Right$(String$(precisionSpecifier, "0") & v, IIf(precisionSpecifier = 0, Len(v), precisionSpecifier))
                    End If

                    'add C# hex specifier, apply specified casing:
                    '(VB6 hex specifier would cause Format() to reverse the formatting):
                    v = "0x" & IIf(formatSpecifier = "X", UCase$(v), LCase$(v))
                    escapeHex = True

                    Case Else
                        If IsNumeric(formatSpecifier) And val(formatGroup) = 0 Then
                            formatSpecifier = formatGroup
                            v = Format(v, formatGroup)
                        Else
                            Err.Raise ERR_FORMAT_EXCEPTION, _
                                ERR_SOURCE, ERR_MSG_INVALID_FORMAT_STRING
                        End If
                End Select

                GoTo ApplyStringFormat


DateTimeFormatSpecifiers:
                Select Case formatSpecifier

                    Case "c", "C" 'CUSTOM date/time format
                    'let VB Format() parse precision specifier as is:
                        thisFormat = precisionString

                    Case "d" 'SHORT DATE format
                        thisFormat = "ddddd"

                    Case "D" 'LONG DATE format
                        thisFormat = "dddddd"

                    Case "f" 'FULL DATE format (short)
                        thisFormat = "dddddd h:mm AM/PM"

                    Case "F" 'FULL DATE format (long)
                        thisFormat = "dddddd ttttt"

                    Case "g"
                        thisFormat = "ddddd hh:mm AM/PM"

                    Case "G"
                        thisFormat = "ddddd ttttt"

                    Case "s" 'SORTABLE DATETIME format
                        thisFormat = "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss"

                    Case "t" 'SHORT TIME format
                        thisFormat = "hh:mm AM/PM"

                    Case "T" 'LONG TIME format
                        thisFormat = "ttttt"

                    Case Else
                        Err.Raise ERR_FORMAT_EXCEPTION, _
                            ERR_SOURCE, ERR_MSG_INVALID_FORMAT_STRING
                End Select
                GoTo ApplyStringFormat

            End If


ApplyStringFormat:
            'apply computed format string:
            If thisFormat <> vbNullString Then
                formattedValue = Format(v, thisFormat)
            Else
                formattedValue = v
            End If


AlignFormattedValue:
            'apply specified alignment specifier:
            If alignmentSpecifier <> vbNullString Then

                alignmentPadding = Abs(CInt(alignmentSpecifier))
                If CInt(alignmentSpecifier) < 0 Then
                    'negative: left-justified alignment
                    If alignmentPadding - Len(formattedValue) > 0 Then _
                        formattedValue = formattedValue & _
                            String$(alignmentPadding - Len(formattedValue), PADDING_CHAR)
                Else
                    'positive: right-justified alignment
                    If alignmentPadding - Len(formattedValue) > 0 Then _
                        formattedValue = String$(alignmentPadding - Len(formattedValue), PADDING_CHAR) & formattedValue
                End If
            End If

            'Replace C# hex specifier with VB6 hex specifier, only if hex specifier was introduced in this function:
            If (Not useLiteral And escapeHex) And StringContains(formattedValue, "0x") Then formattedValue = Replace$(formattedValue, "0x", "&H")

            'replace all occurrences of placeholder {i} with their formatted values:
            return_value = Replace(return_value, thisString, formattedValue, Count:=1)

            'reset before reiterating:
            thisFormat = vbNullString
        Next


checkEscapes:
        'if there's no more backslashes, don't bother checking for the rest:
        If useLiteral Or Not StringContains(return_value, "\") Then GoTo normalExit
        Dim escape As New EscapeSequence
        Dim escapes As New Collection
        escapes.Add escape.Create("\n", vbNewLine), "0"
        escapes.Add escape.Create("\q", Chr$(34)), "1"
        escapes.Add escape.Create("\t", vbTab), "2"
        escapes.Add escape.Create("\a", Chr$(7)), "3"
        escapes.Add escape.Create("\b", Chr$(8)), "4"
        escapes.Add escape.Create("\v", Chr$(13)), "5"
        escapes.Add escape.Create("\f", Chr$(14)), "6"
        escapes.Add escape.Create("\r", Chr$(15)), "7"

        For i = 0 To escapes.Count - 1
            Set escape = escapes(CStr(i))
            If StringContains(return_value, escape.EscapeString) Then _
                return_value = Replace(return_value, escape.EscapeString, escape.ReplacementString)

            If Not StringContains(return_value, "\") Then _
                GoTo normalExit
        Next

        'replace "ASCII (oct)" escape sequence
        Set regex = New RegExp
        regex.pattern = "\\(\d{3})"
        regex.IgnoreCase = True
        regex.Global = True
        Set matches = regex.Execute(format_string)

        Dim char As Long
        If matches.Count <> 0 Then
            For Each thisMatch In matches
                p = thisMatch.SubMatches(0)
                '"p" contains the octal number representing the ASCII code we're after:
                p = "&O" & p 'prepend octal prefix
                char = CLng(p)
                return_value = Replace(return_value, thisMatch.value, Chr$(char))
            Next
        End If

        'if there's no more backslashes, don't bother checking for the rest:
        If Not StringContains("\", return_value) Then GoTo normalExit

        'replace "ASCII (hex)" escape sequence
        Set regex = New RegExp
        regex.pattern = "\\x(\w{2})"
        regex.IgnoreCase = True
        regex.Global = True
        Set matches = regex.Execute(format_string)

        If matches.Count <> 0 Then
            For Each thisMatch In matches
                p = thisMatch.SubMatches(0)
                '"p" contains the hex value representing the ASCII code we're after:
                p = "&H" & p 'prepend hex prefix
                char = CLng(p)
                return_value = Replace(return_value, thisMatch.value, Chr$(char))
            Next
        End If

normalExit:
        Set escapes = Nothing
        Set escape = Nothing
        If Not useLiteral And StringContains(return_value, Chr$(27)) Then _
            return_value = Replace(return_value, Chr$(27), "\")
        StringFormat = return_value
End Function
```

I'm looking for a way to factor out the two (quite huge) `Select...Case` blocks, and to improve readability in general.

Note that this uses [StringContains](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30816/a-more-readable-instr-stringcontains) functions, and I should add a disclaimer about the fact that most of this code is already posted as an answer of mine at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534360/implementing-string-format-in-vb6), although I do not consider it *multi-posting*, since I'm actually asking for a code review here.

Comment: I'm thinking of moving parts of this into a class, but I want to stick to a `Public Function` in a simple code module, to avoid breaking existing code (and still be able to call it as any other native vb function, without instanciating anything).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## **Key Points**

- Each `Case` block implements formatting functionality for a specific format specifier.
- `Goto` statements indicate the function *wants* to be broken down into several smaller functions.
- Local variables such as `alignmentSpecifier`, `alignmentPadding`, `precisionString`, `precisionSpecifier`, `formatSpecifier` and all others, could all be eliminated if there was a concept of a "FormatSpecifier" object that held all these values.
- Bringing in `escapeHex` and the C# hex specifier is a hack easily made useless by correctly encapsulating each format specifier.
- `escapes` collection gets rebuilt every time the function is called, which is inefficient; valid escape sequences don't change from one call to the next.
- ASCII (hex & octal) escapes both *desperately want* to be part of that collection.
- Replacing `\\` with ASCII code for <kbd>Esc</kbd> works nicely to get backslashes escaped.

---

**Warning: below code is absolute overkill** - no one in their right minds (I did this just for fun!) would do all this just to format strings in their VB6 or VBA application. However it shows how the monolithic function can be refactored to remove all `Select...Case` blocks and `Goto` statements.

---

## Rewrite

Here's the refactored module-level function - it uses a `Private helper As New StringHelper`, declared at module level ("declarations" section):

```
Public Function StringFormat(format_string As String, ParamArray values()) As String
    Dim valuesArray() As Variant
    valuesArray = values
    StringFormat = helper.StringFormat(format_string, valuesArray)
End Function
```

#### Escape Sequences

The `EscapeSequence` class was annoyingly leaving out ASCII escapes, so I tackled this first:

```
Private Type tEscapeSequence
    EscapeString As String
    ReplacementString As String
    IsAsciiCharacter As Boolean
    AsciiBase As AsciiEscapeBase
End Type

Public Enum AsciiEscapeBase
    Octal
    Hexadecimal
End Enum

Private this As tEscapeSequence
Option Explicit

Public Property Get EscapeString() As String
    EscapeString = this.EscapeString
End Property

Friend Property Let EscapeString(value As String)
    this.EscapeString = value
End Property

Public Property Get ReplacementString() As String
    ReplacementString = this.ReplacementString
End Property

Friend Property Let ReplacementString(value As String)
    this.ReplacementString = value
End Property

Public Property Get IsAsciiCharacter() As Boolean
    IsAsciiCharacter = this.IsAsciiCharacter
End Property

Friend Property Let IsAsciiCharacter(value As Boolean)
    this.IsAsciiCharacter = value
End Property

Public Property Get AsciiBase() As AsciiEscapeBase
    AsciiBase = this.AsciiBase
End Property

Friend Property Let AsciiBase(value As AsciiEscapeBase)
    this.AsciiBase = value
End Property
```

The factory `Create` function was added two optional parameters; one to specify whether the escape sequence indicates an ASCII replacement escape, the other to specify the base (an enum) of the digits representing the ASCII code:

```
Public Function Create(escape As String, replacement As String, _
                       Optional ByVal isAsciiReplacement As Boolean = False, _
                       Optional ByVal base As AsciiEscapeBase = Octal) As EscapeSequence

    Dim result As New EscapeSequence

    result.EscapeString = escape
    result.ReplacementString = replacement
    result.IsAsciiCharacter = isAsciiReplacement
    result.AsciiBase = base

    Set Create = result

End Function
```

Added an `Execute` method here - all escape sequences boil down to the same thing: *replace the `EscapeString` with the `ReplacementString`, so we might as well encapsulate it here. ASCII escapes are a little bit more complex so I put them in their own method:

```
Public Sub Execute(ByRef string_value As String)

    If this.IsAsciiCharacter Then
        ProcessAsciiEscape string_value, this.EscapeString

    ElseIf StringContains(string_value, this.EscapeString) Then
        string_value = Replace(string_value, this.EscapeString, this.ReplacementString)

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub ProcessAsciiEscape(ByRef format_string As String, _
                               ByVal regexPattern As String)

    Dim regex As RegExp, matches As MatchCollection, thisMatch As Match
    Dim prefix As String, char As Long

    If Not StringContains(format_string, "\") Then Exit Sub

    Set regex = New RegExp
    regex.pattern = regexPattern
    regex.IgnoreCase = True
    regex.Global = True

    Select Case this.AsciiBase
        Case AsciiEscapeBase.Octal
            prefix = "&O"

        Case AsciiEscapeBase.Hexadecimal
            prefix = "&H"

    End Select

    Set matches = regex.Execute(format_string)        
    For Each thisMatch In matches
        char = CLng(prefix & thisMatch.SubMatches(0))
        format_string = Replace(format_string, thisMatch.value, Chr$(char))

    Next

    Set regex = Nothing
    Set matches = Nothing

End Sub
```

This puts escape sequences to bed, at least for now.

### Format Specifiers

Each match in the main RegEx stands for a placeholder (something potentially looking like "{0,-10:C2}"); if we can call those "format specifiers", they can probably deserve their own `StringFormatSpecifier` class as well - the *precision specifier* is normally an `Integer`, but in the custom date format it's also taking a `String` so we'll make `Precision` a get-only property that's set when assigning `CustomSpecifier`:

```
Private Type tSpecifier
    Index As Integer
    identifier As String
    AlignmentSpecifier As Integer
    PrecisionSpecifier As Integer
    CustomSpecifier As String
End Type

Private this As tSpecifier
Option Explicit

Public Property Get Index() As Integer
    Index = this.Index
End Property

Public Property Let Index(value As Integer)
    this.Index = value
End Property   

Public Property Get identifier() As String
    identifier = this.identifier
End Property

Public Property Let identifier(value As String)
    this.identifier = value
End Property

Public Property Get Alignment() As Integer
    Alignment = this.AlignmentSpecifier
End Property

Public Property Let Alignment(value As Integer)
    this.AlignmentSpecifier = value
End Property

Public Property Get Precision() As Integer
    Precision = this.PrecisionSpecifier
End Property

Public Property Get CustomSpecifier() As String
    CustomSpecifier = this.CustomSpecifier
End Property

Public Property Let CustomSpecifier(value As String)
    this.CustomSpecifier = value
    If IsNumeric(value) And val(value) <> 0 Then this.PrecisionSpecifier = CInt(value)
End Property
```

All that's missing is a way to put all the pieces back together to perform the actual replacement - either we store the original string or we implement a `ToString` function:

```
Public Function ToString() As String
    ToString = "{" & this.Index & _
                     IIf(this.AlignmentSpecifier <> 0, _
                         "," & this.AlignmentSpecifier, vbNullString) & _
                     IIf(this.identifier <> vbNullString, _
                         ":" & this.identifier, vbNullString) & _
                     IIf(this.CustomSpecifier <> vbNullString, _
                         this.CustomSpecifier, vbNullString) & "}"
End Function
```

This puts another important piece to bed.

### VB6 Interface?

If we encapsulated how each format specifier works into its own class, odds are we'd get over a dozen of *very* similar classes. If only we were in .net, we could create an interface for this, right? Very few people know that *VB6 also supports interfaces*. In fact, any class can be *implemented* by any other.

So the `IStringFormatIdentifier` interface/class looks like this:

```
Option Explicit

'returns a format string suitable for use with VB6's native Format() function.
Public Function GetFormatString(specifier As StringFormatSpecifier) As String
End Function

'returns the formatted value.
Public Function GetFormattedValue(value As Variant, _
                                  specifier As StringFormatSpecifier) As String
End Function

'compares specified format identifier with implementation-defined one, 
'returns true if format is applicable.
Public Function IsIdentifierMatch(specifier As StringFormatSpecifier) As Boolean
End Function
```

This interface needs an implementation of it for each and every single `Case` block of the original code - not going to list them all here, but this is `GeneralNumericStringFormatIdentifier` (the most complicated one); notice that doing this has also eliminated the recursive function calls:

```
Implements IStringFormatIdentifier
Option Explicit

Private Function IStringFormatIdentifier_GetFormatString(specifier As StringFormatSpecifier) As String
    IStringFormatIdentifier_GetFormatString = vbNullString
End Function

Private Function IStringFormatIdentifier_GetFormattedValue(value As Variant, specifier As StringFormatSpecifier) As String

    Dim result As String
    Dim exponentialNotation As String
    Dim power As Integer
    Dim exponentialFormat As New ExponentialStringFormatIdentifier
    Dim fixedPointFormat As New FixedPointStringFormatIdentifier
    Dim decimalFormat As New DecimalStringFormatIdentifier

    Dim formatSpecifier As New StringFormatSpecifier
    formatSpecifier.Alignment = specifier.Alignment
    formatSpecifier.CustomSpecifier = specifier.CustomSpecifier

    If StringMatchesAny(TypeName(value), "Integer", "Long") Then

        formatSpecifier.identifier = IIf(specifier.identifier = "G", "D", "d")
        result = decimalFormat.GetFormattedValue(value, formatSpecifier)

    ElseIf TypeName(value) = "Double" Then

        formatSpecifier.identifier = IIf(specifier.identifier = "G", "E", "e")
        exponentialNotation = exponentialFormat.GetFormattedValue(value, formatSpecifier)
        power = exponentialFormat.GetPower(exponentialNotation)

        If power > -5 And Abs(power) < specifier.Precision Then

            formatSpecifier.identifier = IIf(specifier.identifier = "G", "F", "f")
            result = fixedPointFormat.GetFormattedValue(value, formatSpecifier)

        Else

            result = exponentialNotation

        End If

    End If

    IStringFormatIdentifier_GetFormattedValue = result
    Set exponentialFormat = Nothing
    Set fixedPointFormat = Nothing
    Set decimalFormat = Nothing
    Set formatSpecifier = Nothing

End Function

Public Function GetFormattedValue(value As Variant, specifier As StringFormatSpecifier) As String
    GetFormattedValue = IStringFormatIdentifier_GetFormattedValue(value, specifier)
End Function

Private Function IStringFormatIdentifier_IsIdentifierMatch(specifier As StringFormatSpecifier) As Boolean
    IStringFormatIdentifier_IsIdentifierMatch = UCase$(specifier.identifier) = "G"
End Function
```

Once every format identifier ("C", "D", "N", etc.) has its implementation of the `IStringFormatIdentifier` interface, we're ready to initialize everything we need, **once**.

### The StringHelper class

Diving into the `StringHelper` class, the "declarations" section contains the error-handling constants, the default padding character and a private type that defines the encapsulated properties (I just do that in every class I write):

```
Private Const ERR_FORMAT_EXCEPTION As Long = vbObjectError Or 9001
Private Const ERR_SOURCE As String = "StringHelper"
Private Const ERR_MSG_INVALID_FORMAT_STRING As String = "Invalid format string."
Private Const ERR_MSG_FORMAT_EXCEPTION As String = "The number indicating an argument to format is less than zero, or greater than or equal to the length of the args array."

Private Type tString
    PaddingCharacter As String * 1
    EscapeSequences As New Collection
    NumericSpecifiers As New Collection
    DateTimeSpecifiers As New Collection
End Type

Private Const PADDING_CHAR As String * 1 = " "

Private this As tString
Option Base 0
Option Explicit
```

Method `Class_Initialize` is where all the one-time stuff happens - this is where escape sequences, numeric and datetime specifiers are initialized:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    If this.PaddingCharacter = vbNullString Then this.PaddingCharacter = PADDING_CHAR

    InitEscapeSequences
    InitNumericSpecifiers
    InitDateTimeSpecifiers

End Sub

Private Sub InitEscapeSequences()

    Dim factory As New EscapeSequence
    Set this.EscapeSequences = New Collection

    this.EscapeSequences.Add factory.Create("\n", vbNewLine)
    this.EscapeSequences.Add factory.Create("\q", Chr$(34))
    this.EscapeSequences.Add factory.Create("\t", vbTab)
    this.EscapeSequences.Add factory.Create("\a", Chr$(7))
    this.EscapeSequences.Add factory.Create("\b", Chr$(8))
    this.EscapeSequences.Add factory.Create("\v", Chr$(13))
    this.EscapeSequences.Add factory.Create("\f", Chr$(14))
    this.EscapeSequences.Add factory.Create("\r", Chr$(15))
    this.EscapeSequences.Add factory.Create("\\x(\w{2})", 0, True, Hexadecimal)
    this.EscapeSequences.Add factory.Create("\\(\d{3})", 0, True, Octal)

    Set factory = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub InitNumericSpecifiers()

    Set this.NumericSpecifiers = New Collection
    this.NumericSpecifiers.Add New CurrencyStringFormatIdentifier
    this.NumericSpecifiers.Add New DecimalStringFormatIdentifier
    this.NumericSpecifiers.Add New GeneralNumericStringFormatIdentifier
    this.NumericSpecifiers.Add New PercentStringFormatIdentifier
    this.NumericSpecifiers.Add New FixedPointStringFormatIdentifier
    this.NumericSpecifiers.Add New ExponentialStringFormatIdentifier
    this.NumericSpecifiers.Add New HexStringFormatIdentifier
    this.NumericSpecifiers.Add New RoundTripStringFormatIdentifier
    this.NumericSpecifiers.Add New NumericPaddingStringFormatIdentifier

End Sub

Private Sub InitDateTimeSpecifiers()

    Set this.DateTimeSpecifiers = New Collection
    this.DateTimeSpecifiers.Add New CustomDateFormatIdentifier
    this.DateTimeSpecifiers.Add New FullDateLongStringFormatSpecifier
    this.DateTimeSpecifiers.Add New FullDateShortStringFormatIdentifier
    this.DateTimeSpecifiers.Add New GeneralLongDateTimeStringFormatIdentifier
    this.DateTimeSpecifiers.Add New GeneralShortDateTimeStringFormatIdentifier
    this.DateTimeSpecifiers.Add New LongDateFormatIdentifier
    this.DateTimeSpecifiers.Add New LongTimeStringFormatIdentifier
    this.DateTimeSpecifiers.Add New ShortDateFormatIdentifier
    this.DateTimeSpecifiers.Add New SortableDateTimeStringFormatIdentifier

End Sub
```

To make the `PaddingCharacter` configurable, it only needs to be exposed as a property.

So let's recap here, we have:

- A collection of escape sequences that know how to to process themselves
- A collection of numeric specifiers that know how to process themselves
- A collection of date/time specifiers that know how to process themselves

All we're missing is a function that will take a `format_string`, validate it and return a collection of `StringFormatSpecifier`. The regular expression we're using to do this can also be simplified a bit - unfortunately this doesn't make it run any faster (performance-wise, this function is really where the bottleneck is):

```
Private Function GetFormatSpecifiers(ByVal format_string As String, valuesCount As Integer) As Collection
'executes a regular expression against format_string to extract all placeholders into a MatchCollection

    Dim regex As New RegExp
    Dim matches As MatchCollection
    Dim thisMatch As Match

    Dim result As New Collection
    Dim specifier As StringFormatSpecifier

    Dim csvIndices As String
    Dim uniqueCount As Integer
    Dim largestIndex As Integer

    regex.pattern = "\{(\w+)(\,\-?\d+)?(\:[^}]+)?\}"

    ' literal {
    ' [1] numbered captured group, any number of repetitions (Index)
    '    alphanumeric, one or more repetitions
    ' [2] numbered captured group, zero or one repetitions (AlignmentSpecifier)
    '    literal ,
    '    literal -, zero or one repetitions
    '    any digit, one or more repetitions
    ' [3] numbered captured group, zero or one repetitions (FormatSpecifier)
    '    literal :
    '    any character except '}', one or more repetitions
    ' literal }

    regex.IgnoreCase = True
    regex.Global = True

    Set matches = regex.Execute(format_string)
    For Each thisMatch In matches

        Set specifier = New StringFormatSpecifier
        specifier.Index = CInt(thisMatch.SubMatches(0))

        If Not StringContains(csvIndices, specifier.Index & ",") Then
            uniqueCount = uniqueCount + 1
            csvIndices = csvIndices & specifier.Index & ","
        End If
        If specifier.Index > largestIndex Then largestIndex = specifier.Index

        If Not thisMatch.SubMatches(1) = vbEmpty Then specifier.Alignment = CInt(Replace(CStr(thisMatch.SubMatches(1)), ",", vbNullString))
        If Not thisMatch.SubMatches(2) = vbEmpty Then
            specifier.identifier = Left(Replace(CStr(thisMatch.SubMatches(2)), ":", vbNullString), 1)
            specifier.CustomSpecifier = Replace(CStr(thisMatch.SubMatches(2)), ":" & specifier.identifier, vbNullString)
        End If

        result.Add specifier
    Next

    If matches.Count > 0 And (uniqueCount <> valuesCount) Or (largestIndex >= uniqueCount) Or valuesCount = 0) Then Err.Raise ERR_FORMAT_EXCEPTION, ERR_SOURCE, ERR_MSG_FORMAT_EXCEPTION

    Set GetFormatSpecifiers = result
    Set regex = Nothing
    Set matches = Nothing

End Function
```

The actual `StringFormat` function takes an array of `Variant` sent from the module function's `ParamArray values()` parameter; taking a `ParamArray` here as well would make things more complicated than they already are.

So all the function really needs to do, is loop through all specifiers in `format_string`, and apply the appropriate format specifier's formatting. Then apply the alignment specifier and execute escape sequences (unless `format_string` starts with a "@") - with everything properly encapsulated in specialized objects, this should leave a pretty readable implementation:

```
Public Function StringFormat(format_string As String, values() As Variant) As String

    Dim result As String
    result = format_string

    Dim specifiers As Collection
    Dim specifier As StringFormatSpecifier
    Set specifiers = GetFormatSpecifiers(result, UBound(values) + 1)

    Dim useLiteral As Boolean 
    'when format_string starts with "@", escapes are not replaced 
    '(string is treated as a literal string with placeholders)
    useLiteral = StringStartsWith("@", result)

    'remove the "@" literal specifier from the result string
    If useLiteral Then result = Right(result, Len(result) - 1) 


    'replace escaped backslashes with 'ESC' character [Chr$(27)] 
    'to optimize escape sequences evaluation:
    If Not useLiteral And StringContains(result, "\\") Then _
        result = Replace(result, "\\", Chr$(27))

    Dim formattedValue As String
    Dim alignmentPadding As Integer
    Dim identifier As IStringFormatIdentifier
    Dim identifierFound As Boolean

    For Each specifier In specifiers

        formattedValue = values(specifier.Index)
        identifierFound = (specifier.identifier = vbNullString)

        If IsNumeric(values(specifier.Index)) Then

            For Each identifier In this.NumericSpecifiers
                If identifier.IsIdentifierMatch(specifier) Then

                    identifierFound = True
                    formattedValue = identifier.GetFormattedValue(values(specifier.Index), specifier)

                End If
            Next

        ElseIf TypeName(values(specifier.Index)) = "Date" Then

            For Each identifier In this.DateTimeSpecifiers
                If identifier.IsIdentifierMatch(specifier) Then

                    identifierFound = True
                    formattedValue = identifier.GetFormattedValue(values(specifier.Index), specifier)

                End If
            Next

        End If

        If Not identifierFound Then Err.Raise ERR_FORMAT_EXCEPTION, ERR_SOURCE, ERR_MSG_INVALID_FORMAT_STRING

        alignmentPadding = Abs(specifier.Alignment)
        If specifier.Alignment < 0 Then

            'negative: left-justified alignment
            If alignmentPadding - Len(formattedValue) > 0 Then _
                formattedValue = formattedValue & String$(alignmentPadding - Len(formattedValue), this.PaddingCharacter)

        ElseIf specifier.Alignment > 0 Then

            'positive: right-justified alignment
            If alignmentPadding - Len(formattedValue) > 0 Then _
                formattedValue = String$(alignmentPadding - Len(formattedValue), this.PaddingCharacter) & formattedValue

        End If

        'replace all occurrences of placeholder {i} with their formatted values:
        result = Replace(result, specifier.ToString, formattedValue)

    Next

    Dim escape As EscapeSequence
    If Not useLiteral And StringContains(result, "\") Then
        For Each escape In this.EscapeSequences
            escape.Execute result
        Next
    End If

    If Not useLiteral And StringContains(result, Chr$(27)) Then result = Replace(result, Chr$(27), "\")
    StringFormat = result

End Function
```

Feel free to comment below! :)

Comment: I should add that performance tests calling `StringFormat("{0,20}", "test string")` 10,000 times in a loop, with the monolithic function average at around 2730 (2703-2797) milliseconds, while the refactored and definitely more object-oriented version averages at around 2390 (2312-2594) milliseconds, which is a subtle but welcome improvement!

Comment: And I thought Winston Ewert was the only one here with the longest answers. :-P Kudos for such a lengthy (and assumably great) self-answer contribution.  It's a shame I have no idea what any of this means.

Comment: Thanks! Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be(v=vs.95).aspx - I think this implementation is the most useful code I've ever written in VB6 (works in VBA - Alt+F11 in Excel, insert a new code module and enjoy .net-like string formatting :)). I didn't really mean to self-answer, it's just rewriting it in a more OOP way was itching... so I figured I'd post the refactored version as a self-answer, but I'm not self-accepting it just yet - in case I actually get a review... I take it as some sort of "practice review" :)

Comment: As this IS an answer, no one can properly do a full review if needed.  Any criticisms and such would be limited to comments.  Moreover, don't be afraid to self-answer (as long as it's still intended to be an answer).  I've done so before, but haven't received votes on any of them.  I think it's kinda hard to self-answer on CR, especially if you yourself can't figure out one of the best reviewed versions of your code.

Comment: I'm sure there are a couple nasty bugs lurking in there... The thing with a self-answer on CR is that the self-answer could be subject to another code review on its own - self-answering sounds like saying "okay nevermind what's above; I made it better, take a look at this instead"... interestingly, "self-answer" yields only 2 irrelevant results on meta...

Comment: In that case, there would have to be another answer to review that answer.  [Answerception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception)?

Comment: I would like to use this code because it's darn fantastic. However you've missed some of the definitions out for the sake of the review, and so as it stands I can't use this fully. Would you be willing to share the complete code or provide a link to it? Maybe a cheeky .xlam ;) if it's kicking around

Comment: @Greedo I had it all on an old computer.. which died in 2015. This is all that's left of it :-/  the original function on the SO post is self-contained though, no?

Comment: I think I already mentioned to you Matt but I was reminded of this recently. I resurrected this code and [put it on github](https://github.com/Greedquest/VBA-Gems), and also here is a [downloadable .xlam](https://github.com/Greedquest/VBA-Gems/blob/main/CSharpish%20String%20Format/String%20Format.xlam?raw=true) version which can be referenced from an excel project, and gives both `StringFormat` (updated) and `FormerStringFormat` (original) functions. I seem to remember the escape sequences may not be working correctly, I had to make some guesses, but this is 90% of the way there

Answer (score 12):

Two small things I noticed at a glance, both involve this code and it looks like it made it into your refactored version as well.

> ```
>   'some error-handling constants:
>     Const ERR_FORMAT_EXCEPTION As Long = vbObjectError Or 9001
>     Const ERR_ARGUMENT_NULL_EXCEPTION As Long = vbObjectError Or 9002
>     Const ERR_ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION As Long = vbObjectError Or 9003
> ```

Why on Earth are you bitwise `Or`ing these? Just add them like <s>in the documentation</s> every other sane developer.

```
    'some error-handling constants:
    Const ERR_FORMAT_EXCEPTION As Long = vbObjectError + 9001
    Const ERR_ARGUMENT_NULL_EXCEPTION As Long = vbObjectError + 9002
    Const ERR_ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION As Long = vbObjectError + 9003
```

While you're at it, why isn't this an `Enum`?

```
'some error-handling constants:
Public Enum FormatError
    ERR_FORMAT_EXCEPTION = vbObjectError + 9001
    ERR_ARGUMENT_NULL_EXCEPTION
    ERR_ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION
End Enum
```

Comment: Dude, where have you been all this time!

Comment: Wasting time on Stack Overflow.

Comment: "Because bitwise `Or` is 'correct'." I agree with the `Enum` though.

Comment: How is the `Or` correct @MarkHurd? Sure, it works and is completely equivalent in this scenario, but your average VB dev is going to stare at the screen uttering "WTF". In my mind, the correct way is the way that's easy to understand.

Comment: @RubberDuck You've caused me to go back and quickly review my VB6 code: I used `Or` mostly, but sometimes I did something like `Const ErrBase = vbObjectError Or 1000 : Err.Raise ErrBase + 19`. Anyway, the other [facility codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231198.aspx) mostly aren't relevant to VB6 code, although we should probably now use &hA0000000 instead anyway.

Comment: in the Enum why does only the first have the + \d{4} please?

Comment: @QHarr the rest of them increment by 1 automatically. Omitting the +2, +3, etc just makes for easier maintenance.

Comment: @RubberDuck Thanks. I was guessing something like that. And is there a reason for the number being 9001 ?  As opposed to say 901 ?

Comment: You always add some number to the `vbObjectError` constant, but there’s no real meaning to what that number is other than what we assign to it. You want it to be unique so that it’s easy to find the error code. When I was regularly developing VBA, my dept kept a spreadsheet full of the custom error codes we had created so we didn’t duplicate and they were easy to look up.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, note that this is "reviewing" the code in the self-answer:

The `Replace` calls effectively implementing the missing `RemoveFrom` method isn't needed here. You could add extra brackets to the `RegEx`, and just extract the captures you want, but here you know the position and length of what you're skipping, so just use `Mid$`.  I.e. this:

```
    If Not thisMatch.SubMatches(1) = vbEmpty Then specifier.Alignment = CInt(Replace(CStr(thisMatch.SubMatches(1)), ",", vbNullString))
    If Not thisMatch.SubMatches(2) = vbEmpty Then
        specifier.identifier = Left(Replace(CStr(thisMatch.SubMatches(2)), ":", vbNullString), 1)
        specifier.CustomSpecifier = Replace(CStr(thisMatch.SubMatches(2)), ":" & specifier.identifier, vbNullString)
    End If
```

becomes this:

```
    If Not thisMatch.SubMatches(1) = vbEmpty Then specifier.Alignment = CInt(Mid$(CStr(thisMatch.SubMatches(1)), 2))
    If Not thisMatch.SubMatches(2) = vbEmpty Then
        specifier.identifier = Mid$(CStr(thisMatch.SubMatches(2)), 2, 1)
        specifier.CustomSpecifier = Mid$(CStr(thisMatch.SubMatches(2)), 3)
    End If
```

*BUG*

To avoid counting wrong for the pedantic case of `"{2}{11}{1}..."`, initialise `csvIndices` to `","` and search for `"," & specifier.Index & ","`.