# Simple Caesar Cipher Function

Tags: vba, caesar-cipher

For no particular reason, I wanted to create a function that would take a string and "encrypt" it via [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher). This function takes a string and shifts the letters left or right (in the alphabet) depending on the input. Shift right(2) for instance would be -

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZAB
```

The UDF:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function CaesarCipher(ByVal TextToEncrypt As String, ByVal CaesarShift As Long) As String

    'Positive means shift to right e.g. "A" Shift 1 returns "B"
    Dim IsPositive As Boolean
    IsPositive = True
    If CaesarShift < 0 Then IsPositive = False
    CaesarShift = Abs(CaesarShift)

    Dim OutputText As String
    TextToEncrypt = UCase(TextToEncrypt)

    If CaesarShift > 26 Then
        CaesarShift = CaesarShift Mod 26
    End If

    If IsPositive Then
          OutputText = ShiftRight(TextToEncrypt, CaesarShift)
    Else: OutputText = ShiftLeft(TextToEncrypt, CaesarShift)
    End If

    CaesarCipher = OutputText
End Function
```

The shifting functions:

```
Private Function ShiftRight(ByVal ShiftString As String, ByVal ShiftQuantity As Long) As String

    Dim TextLength As Long
    TextLength = Len(ShiftString)

    Dim CipherText As String
    Dim CharacterCode As Long
    Dim AsciiIndex As Long
    Dim AsciiIdentifier() As Long
    ReDim AsciiIdentifier(1 To TextLength)

    For AsciiIndex = 1 To TextLength
        CharacterCode = Asc(Mid(ShiftString, AsciiIndex, 1))
        If CharacterCode + ShiftQuantity > 90 Then
            CharacterCode = CharacterCode - 26 + ShiftQuantity
        ElseIf CharacterCode = 32 Then GoTo Spaces
        Else:  CharacterCode = CharacterCode + ShiftQuantity
        End If
Spaces:
        AsciiIdentifier(AsciiIndex) = CharacterCode
    Next

        For AsciiIndex = 1 To TextLength
            CipherText = CipherText & Chr(AsciiIdentifier(AsciiIndex))
        Next
    ShiftRight = CipherText
End Function
```

---

```
Private Function ShiftLeft(ByVal ShiftString As String, ByVal ShiftQuantity As Long) As String

    Dim TextLength As Long
    TextLength = Len(ShiftString)

    Dim CipherText As String
    Dim CharacterCode As Long
    Dim AsciiIndex As Long
    Dim AsciiIdentifier() As Long
    ReDim AsciiIdentifier(1 To TextLength)

    For AsciiIndex = 1 To TextLength
        CharacterCode = Asc(Mid(ShiftString, AsciiIndex, 1))
        If CharacterCode = 32 Then GoTo Spaces
        If CharacterCode - ShiftQuantity < 65 Then
            CharacterCode = CharacterCode + 26 - ShiftQuantity
        Else: CharacterCode = CharacterCode - ShiftQuantity
        End If
Spaces:
        AsciiIdentifier(AsciiIndex) = CharacterCode
    Next

        For AsciiIndex = 1 To TextLength
            CipherText = CipherText & Chr(AsciiIdentifier(AsciiIndex))
        Next
    ShiftLeft = CipherText
End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Just some things that jump out at me:**

[Standard VBA Naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s46s4ew(v=vs.140).aspx) have `camelCase` for local variables, and `PascalCase` only for sub/function names and Module/Global Variables. This allows you to tell at a glance if the variable you're looking at is local to your procedure, or coming from somewhere else.

---

I would probably use `EncryptUsingCaesarCypher` as your function name. It's more descriptive and closer to what it actually does.

```
`Text = CaesarCypher(text)
```

versus

```
`Text = EncryptUsingCaesarCypher(text)
```

Other than that, your naming is pretty solid.

---

Why separate functions for `ShiftLeft` and `ShiftRight`? The code in both is heavily-repeated and could be easily combined into a `Shift(ByVal shiftValue as Long)` function that handles positive and negative. This also lets you cut out all that messing around with `isPositve` and `Abs(shift)`

Comment: The only way I could figure out to combine those two would be using cases because depending on positive or negative the values they are compared to change. And cases didn't seem much better. Thanks, I didn't actually know there was a camelCase and PascalCase or the difference.

Comment: IMO, just combine the functions and do all the comparisons/cases in one. It's going to end up with roughly the same amount of code, but now you're going to have a universal (shift string) function which can handle any shift paramater, rather than 2 competing ones where you have to know beforehand if you're shifting up or down. You could even just wrap your +- shift functions under a main "ShiftString" function which will itself determine positive or negative then call the appropriate function.

Answer (score 5):

Minor note. This line:

> ```
> If CaesarShift < 0 Then IsPositive = False
> ```

Would probably be more clear as an assignment.

```
IsPositive = ( CaesarShift >= 0 )
```

Albeit a matter a preference, I prefer the latter because it puts the variable that's being written to completely on the left of the statement. Doing it this way also reduces the total number of operations.

(Not that it's a performance bottleneck anyway, but it's important to know how to spot these things when you eventually do have a bottleneck you need to take care of.)

Answer (score 4):

in your `CaesarCipher` function you create an extra boolean that you don't really need

> ```
> Public Function CaesarCipher(ByVal TextToEncrypt As String, ByVal CaesarShift As Long) As String
>
>     'Positive means shift to right e.g. "A" Shift 1 returns "B"
>     Dim IsPositive As Boolean
>     IsPositive = True
>     If CaesarShift < 0 Then IsPositive = False
>     CaesarShift = Abs(CaesarShift)
>
>     Dim OutputText As String
>     TextToEncrypt = UCase(TextToEncrypt)
>
>     If CaesarShift > 26 Then
>         CaesarShift = CaesarShift Mod 26
>     End If
>
>     If IsPositive Then
>           OutputText = ShiftRight(TextToEncrypt, CaesarShift)
>     Else: OutputText = ShiftLeft(TextToEncrypt, CaesarShift)
>     End If
>
>     CaesarCipher = OutputText
> End Function
> ```

I suggest you change the last if/then statement to check whether the the shift is zero, positive or negative, if it is zero you don't have to call either shift and you save processing, if it is positive you don't need to call the absolute function at all, so you shave a lot of data processing if the shift is positive.

only if the shift is negative do you have to call the absolute function.  here is what it looks like after we change the if/else statement and remove the boolean.

```
Public Function CaesarCipher(ByVal TextToEncrypt As String, ByVal CaesarShift As Long) As String

    Dim OutputText As String
    TextToEncrypt = UCase(TextToEncrypt)

    If CaesarShift > 26 Then
        CaesarShift = CaesarShift Mod 26
    End If

    If CaesarShift = 0 Then
        OutputText = TextToEncrypt
    ElseIf CaesarShift > 0 Then
        OutputText = ShiftRight(TextToEncrypt, CaesarShift)
    Else
        CaesarShift = Abs(CaesarShift)
        OutputText = ShiftLeft(TextToEncrypt, CaesarShift)
    End If

    CaesarCipher = OutputText
End Function
```

Comment: That is a good way to avoid the boolean I didn't think of, thanks! Re: long vs integer, via the [SO Answer to Why Use Integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520) there's reference in the [office dev center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164506(v=office.10).aspx) that integers are silently converted to long in VBA, which was surprising to me when [zak mentioned it](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/117381/75587) in an answer and I went looking for the documentation. Very valid point otherwise.

Comment: That is interesting, although that page doesn't mention Short integers, I wonder if they too are converted to Long integers?  it seems that there is a slight performance benefit to using a long over an integer because of the silent conversion of the integer to a long because the long won't need to do the extra conversion.

Comment: I've never used `short` but I'm pretty sure it's not a data type for VBA [ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264568.aspx). There's single and double, but they are floating point.

Comment: I tried to substitute short, int16, system.int16 or Long and none of them worked in the VBA Macro, @Raystafarian. so Long is the most appropriate.

Comment: Lol. @Malachi a VB6 Integer *is* a Short. A VB6 Long is an (.Net) Integer.

Comment: @RubberDuck, Mat also told me that in chat, lol