# VBA Text Class, sort of like .NET

Tags: object-oriented, strings, vba

This is my first attempt at writing some reusable OOP code. The problem I'm trying to simplify is the confusing (at least to me) structure of VBA string manipulation.

**Example**

```
Dim SomeString As String
SomeString = "1234abc"
SomeString = UCase(Left(StrReverse("1234abc"), 3))
```

I've been using VBA long enough, that I get it. Read the expression inside out, but with .NET this is much more intuitive (again, to me) with method chaining. So with that in mind I made the following class which *sort of* have a .NET string quality to them. Be sure to save this `Class` to a file then import it, as I'm setting the default property of this class to be `Value` with the `Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0` Attribute.

**Text Class**

```
Option Explicit
Private pText As String

Public Enum SearchDirection
    StartToEnd
    EndToStart
End Enum

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    pText = vbNullString
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    pText = vbNullString
End Sub

Public Property Get Value() As String
Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0
    Value = pText
End Property

Public Property Let Value(ByVal InputString As String)
    pText = InputString
End Property

Public Function LowerCase() As text
    pText = LCase$(pText)
    Set LowerCase = Me
End Function

Public Function UpperCase() As text
    pText = UCase$(pText)
    Set UpperCase = Me
End Function

Public Function ProperCase() As text
    pText = StrConv(pText, vbProperCase)
    Set ProperCase = Me
End Function

Public Function TrimText() As text
    pText = Trim$(pText)
    Set TrimText = Me
End Function

Public Function LeftTrim() As text
    pText = LTrim$(pText)
    Set LeftTrim = Me
End Function

Public Function RightTrim() As text
    pText = RTrim$(pText)
    Set RightTrim = Me
End Function

Public Function ToByteArray() As Byte()
    ToByteArray = StrConv(pText, vbFromUnicode)
End Function

Public Function ToCharArray() As String()
    Dim tmpArray    As Variant

    tmpArray = VBA.Split(StrConv(pText, vbUnicode), Chr$(0))

    ReDim Preserve tmpArray(LBound(tmpArray) To UBound(tmpArray) - 1)
    ToCharArray = tmpArray
    Erase tmpArray
End Function

Public Function IsInText(ByVal SearchText As String, _
                         Optional ByVal Direction As SearchDirection = SearchDirection.StartToEnd, _
                         Optional ByVal CompareMode As VbCompareMethod = vbTextCompare, _
                         Optional ByVal LookInSearchText As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    If Direction = StartToEnd Then
        If LookInSearchText Then
            IsInText = IIf(InStr(1, SearchText, pText, CompareMode) > 0, True, False)
        Else
            IsInText = IIf(InStr(1, pText, SearchText, CompareMode) > 0, True, False)
        End If
    Else
        If LookInSearchText Then
            IsInText = IIf(InStrRev(1, SearchText, pText, CompareMode) > 0, True, False)
        Else
            IsInText = IIf(InStrRev(1, pText, SearchText, CompareMode) > 0, True, False)
        End If
    End If

End Function

Public Function InTextPosition(ByVal SearchText As String, _
                               Optional ByVal Direction As SearchDirection = SearchDirection.StartToEnd, _
                               Optional ByVal CompareMode As VbCompareMethod = vbTextCompare, _
                               Optional ByVal LookInSearchText As Boolean = False) As Long

    If Direction = StartToEnd Then
        If LookInSearchText Then
            InTextPosition = InStr(1, SearchText, pText, CompareMode)
        Else
            InTextPosition = InStr(1, pText, SearchText, CompareMode)
        End If
    Else
        If LookInSearchText Then
            InTextPosition = InStrRev(1, SearchText, pText, CompareMode)
        Else
            InTextPosition = InStrRev(1, pText, SearchText, CompareMode)
        End If
    End If

End Function

Public Property Get IsTextNull() As Boolean
   IsTextNull = IIf(pText = vbNullString, True, False)
End Property

Public Function Slice(Optional ByVal StartingCharacter As Long = 1, _
                      Optional ByVal EndingCharacter As Long = -1) As text

    If EndingCharacter = StartingCharacter Then EndingCharacter = EndingCharacter + 1

    'Throw an error if the ending character isn't -1, or is less than the starting character
    If EndingCharacter < StartingCharacter And Not EndingCharacter = -1 Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "Text.Slice error", _
                  "You must enter an ending character greater than or equal to the starting character"
        Exit Function
    End If

    If EndingCharacter = -1 Then
        If StartingCharacter >= 1 And Len(pText) > 0 Then pText = Mid$(pText, StartingCharacter, Len(pText))
    Else
        If StartingCharacter >= 1 And Len(pText) > 0 Then pText = Mid$(pText, StartingCharacter, EndingCharacter - StartingCharacter)
    End If

    Set Slice = Me
End Function

Public Function Split(ByVal Delimiter As String, _
                     Optional ByVal Limit As Long = -1, _
                     Optional ByVal CompareMethod As VbCompareMethod = vbTextCompare) As Variant

    Split = VBA.Split(pText, Delimiter, Limit, CompareMethod)
End Function

Public Function Left(ByVal Length As Long) As text
    pText = VBA.Left$(pText, Length)
    Set Left = Me
End Function

Public Function Right(ByVal Length As Long) As text
    pText = VBA.Right$(pText, Length)
    Set Right = Me
End Function

Public Function ReplaceText(ByVal FindText As String, _
                            ByVal ReplaceWith As String, _
                            Optional ByVal Start As Long = 1, _
                            Optional ByVal Count As Long = -1, _
                            Optional ByVal CompareMode As VbCompareMethod = vbTextCompare) As text

    pText = Replace(pText, FindText, ReplaceWith, Start, Count, CompareMode)
    Set ReplaceText = Me
End Function

Public Function ReverseText() As text
    pText = StrReverse(pText)
    Set ReverseText = Me
End Function

Public Property Get Length() As Long
    Length = Len(pText)
End Property

Public Function RegexReplace(ByVal Pattern As String, _
                             Optional ByVal ReplaceWith As String = vbNullString, _
                             Optional ByVal MultiLine As Boolean = True, _
                             Optional ByVal GlobalFlag As Boolean = True, _
                             Optional ByVal IgnoreCase As Boolean = True) As text

    Static RegEx As Object

    If RegEx Is Nothing Then Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With RegEx
        .Pattern = Pattern
        .MultiLine = MultiLine
        .Global = GlobalFlag
        .IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
        pText = .Replace(pText, ReplaceWith)
    End With

    Set RegexReplace = Me
End Function

Public Function RegexMatch(ByVal Pattern As String, _
                           Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = vbNullString, _
                           Optional ByVal GlobalFlag As Boolean = True, _
                           Optional ByVal IgnoreCase As Boolean = True) As text

    Dim i               As Long
    Dim j               As Long
    Dim Matches         As Object
    Dim MatchingValue   As String

    Static RegEx As Object

    If RegEx Is Nothing Then Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With RegEx
        .Pattern = Pattern
        .Global = GlobalFlag
        .IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
        Set Matches = .Execute(pText)
    End With

    For i = 0 To Matches.Count - 1
        If Matches.Item(i).submatches.Count > 0 Then
            For j = 0 To Matches.Item(i).submatches.Count
                MatchingValue = MatchingValue & Delimiter & Matches.Item(i).submatches.Item(j)
            Next
        Else
            MatchingValue = MatchingValue & Delimiter & Matches.Item(i)
        End If
    Next

    If Len(MatchingValue) <> 0 Then MatchingValue = VBA.Right$(MatchingValue, Len(MatchingValue) - Len(Delimiter))

    pText = MatchingValue
    Set RegexMatch = Me
End Function
```

**Client Code Sample**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TextExample()
    Dim newString      As text
    Dim i              As Long
    Dim StringArray()  As String
    Dim AnotherArray() As String

    Set newString = New text

    'The value property is the default for the class, just assign it
    newString = " Hello, World! The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog   "

    'Let's do sample string manipulations but with method chaining
    If newString.IsInText("fox") Then
        Debug.Print "First Example: " & newString.UpperCase.RegexReplace("\s*").Slice(7, 12)
        newString = "Something Else"
        StringArray = newString.UpperCase.ToCharArray

        For i = LBound(StringArray) To UBound(StringArray)
            Debug.Print "Second Example: " & i, StringArray(i)
        Next

        'Another little example of using a regex pattern to find digits
        'then converting to an array
        newString = "12345 ABC 42 Z 13"
        AnotherArray = newString.RegexMatch("\d+", ",").Split(",")

        For i = LBound(AnotherArray) To UBound(AnotherArray)
            Debug.Print "Third Example: " & i, AnotherArray(i)
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

**Where I need some help/guidance**

I'm definitely not proficient writing or thinking from an OOP perspective yet, so I could use some guidance in the following areas:

- Is this approach reasonable from an OOP perspective?
- Naming things is hard, I don't really like "Text" but couldn't think of anything better. Also, not entirely sure my method and property names are great either

Comment: I would have gone with `ToLowerCase`, `ToUpperCase`, and `ToProperCase`. In OOP terms what you have here is similar to a *builder pattern* (with the functions returning `Me`) - I'd consider making it a `StringBuilder` class and adding methods to `Append`. Browse around in the VBA tag, there's an excellent StringBuilder class waiting to be put to good use =)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Yes that StringBuilder class is awesome. I think merging that in here would be worthwhile. Thanks for the feedback :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***"Is this approach reasonable from an OOP perspective?"***:  I think that this self-referencing style of OOP design should work quite well for what you are trying to accomplish.

"***Naming things is hard, I don't really like "Text" but couldn't think of anything better. Also, not entirely sure my method and property names are great either"***: `Text` is good name for the class.  If you want to change it consider:  `ExtString`, `StringPlus`, `NetString` or `Strings`.

### "Any other gotchas or any other feedback would be awesome"

`**IsInText**` and `**InTextPosition**`:  Both VB.Net and the VBA use `Instr` to perform the functions of these two methods.  There is little merit in having a separate function to return a `Boolean` (True or False) value.  After all the VBA evaluates 0 as False and any other number as True.  True itself has a value of -1.  The main reason to have the one `InStr` method is that whoever else that is going to use your class will know its usage, without having to read the code or code docs.  Ehh maybe I am nit-picking .Net does have an `**IndexOF**` method...Nah ditch them and use `**Instr**`

I know that the class is only sorta like the .Net class, I still expected to see `**Clone**`, `**ToString**` and most importantly I think that `**Equals**`, `**ConCat**` and `**Substring**` are absolute must haves.  Adding `EndsWith` and `Format` will also be very useful.  Of course a .Net Format could easily be a class by itself.  `Text.Format("Wouldn't having a {0} be {1}!", "String Formatter","Awesome")`.

`**Slice**`???...oh you mean `**Substring**` ( I was wonder why that was missing).  Use `**Substring**`.  We are after all working with Strings and not Arrays.  You should consider changing the parameter names also `**StartingCharacter**` and `**EndingCharacter**`.  The `Character` suffix makes me think that you are expecting a character.  I don't like the use of `**EndingCharacter**`.  It would be much clearer if you use the `**Mid**` parameters of `**Start**` and `**Length**`.  This function is useful but the naming is confusing.  Consider changing its signature to `Range(Optional StartIndex as long, Optional EndIndex as long)` and add a separate `**Substring**` method.

### `ToCharArray`

> Erase tmpArray

**Note**:  The VBA does a pretty good job of garbage collecting.  Erasing arrays at the end of a subroutine has no real effect.  Similarly, it is rarely necessary to set an Object to Nothing at the end of a subroutine .

It would be interesting to do a speed comparison between the OP's method and this one:

```
Public Function ToCharArray() As String()
    Dim result() As String
    Dim i As Long
    ReDim result(Len(pText))
    For i = 1 To Len(pText)
        result = Mid$(pText, i, 1)
    Next

    ToCharArray = result
End Function
```

Comment: thanks very much for the feedback it is appreciated. I'll definitely add in those methods, there are others I want to add as well, so this was more of "hey, am I on the right track". Agreed your `ToCharArray` method is much cleaner, but splitting by this method always seems to leave an empty string in the last array index, hence the `ReDim Preserve tmpArray(LBound(tmpArray) To UBound(tmpArray) - 1)` to remove that pesky last array item. I'll erase, erase :)

Comment: As soon as I posted, I went to bed, closed my eyes and it hit me about the redim.  So I got up and edited my post.  Anyway, nice work.

Comment: Someone should really merge OP's class with [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/67596/146810) and [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/31000/146810) in some super addin - then we'd be cooking

Comment: @Greedo absolutely!

Comment: IMO `ToString` would be redundant, given `Value`. If the default member attribute can be applied to a method (never tried that, IMO it's more idiomatic to have it on a property), then `ToString` could have it (and then `Value` can be removed).

Comment: Also `Clone` is very much redundant, and `IClonable` was arguably a design mistake in .net; I wouldn't bother with it.

Comment: @Greedo, a super add-in sounds like fun. Maybe that will be my next project, thanks all for the feedback so far :)