# Revisited IsTypeSafe method implementation for "type-safe" List

Tags: vba, type-safety, vb6

Following up on [List<T> implementation for VB6/VBA](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32618/listt-implementation-for-vb6-vba), I'd like some thoughts about the revisited `IsTypeSafe` function, below.

The previous version pretty much implemented VB.net's `Option Strict` setting, by only allowing *widening* numeric type conversions, and preventing implicit conversion between numeric and string data types. This one is more permissive, to a point where I'm torn between ease of use (VB6 isn't .net!) and correctness (it's twisting `Option Strict` by allowing implicit conversions of *in-range* values, i.e. a `Long` with a value of `32` could be added to a `List<Byte>`... **does that help or hinder usability?**).

Given the following private type where `TItem` is the type name of `T` in `List<T>`...

```vb
Private Type tList
    Encapsulated As Collection
    TItem As String
    OptionStrict As Boolean
End Type

Private this As tList
```

The `IsTypeSafe` method's behavior depends on the values of `this.OptionStrict` and `this.TItem`:

- When *this.OptionStrict = True* (the default value; can be modified through a public property), then `IsTypeSafe` only returns `True` when the type of `value` matches exactly with that of `this.TItem`.
- When *this.OptionStrict = False*, then `IsTypeSafe` returns `True` if `value` can be legally converted to the type specified by `this.TItem`; if the value *can* be converted, it *is* converted, so as to avoid having a `List<Integer>` with `Byte` values...
- When *this.TItem = vbNullString*, then `IsTypeSafe` returns `True` systematically, and then `this.TItem` becomes the type name of `value`.

```vb
Public Function IsTypeSafe(value As Variant) As Boolean
'Determines whether a value can be safely added to the List.

    IsTypeSafe = this.TItem = vbNullString Or this.TItem = TypeName(value)
    If IsTypeSafe Or this.OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Select Case this.TItem

        Case "String":
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeString(value)
            If IsTypeSafe Then value = CStr(value)

        Case "Boolean"
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeBoolean(value)
            If IsTypeSafe Then value = CBool(value)

        Case "Byte":
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeByte(value)
            If IsTypeSafe Then value = CByte(value)

        Case "Date":
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeDate(value)
            If IsTypeSafe Then value = CDate(value)

        Case "Integer":
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeInteger(value)
            If IsTypeSafe Then value = CInt(value)

        Case "Long":
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeLong(value)
            If IsTypeSafe Then value = CLng(value)

        Case "Single"
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeSingle(value)
            If IsTypeSafe Then value = CSng(value)

        Case "Double":
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeDouble(value)
            If IsTypeSafe Then value = CDbl(value)

        Case "Currency":
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeCurrency(value)
            If IsTypeSafe Then value = CCur(value)

        Case Else:
            IsTypeSafe = False

    End Select


ErrHandler:
    'swallow overflow errors:
    If Err.Number = 6 Then
        Err.Clear
        IsTypeSafe = False
    End If

End Function
```

The method uses a bunch of `IsSafe[Type](value As Variant) As Boolean` functions that are quite redundant - would there be a clever way to shorten that up?

```vb
Private Function IsSafeString(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim result As String
    result = CStr(value) 'assigning value would be an undesirable side-effect here!
    IsSafeString = (Err.Number = 0)
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function IsSafeDate(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim result As Date
    result = CDate(value) 'assigning value would be an undesirable side-effect here!
    IsSafeDate = (Err.Number = 0)
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function IsSafeByte(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim result As Byte
    result = CByte(value) 'assigning value would be an undesirable side-effect here!
    IsSafeByte = (Err.Number = 0)
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function IsSafeBoolean(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CBool(value) 'assigning value would be an undesirable side-effect here!
    IsSafeBoolean = (Err.Number = 0)        
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function IsSafeCurrency(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim result As Currency
    result = CCur(value) 'assigning value would be an undesirable side-effect here!
    IsSafeCurrency = (Err.Number = 0)
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function IsSafeInteger(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim result As Integer
    result = CInt(value) 'assigning value would be an undesirable side-effect here!
    IsSafeInteger = (Err.Number = 0)
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function IsSafeLong(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim result As Long
    result = CLng(value) 'assigning value would be an undesirable side-effect here!
    IsSafeLong = (Err.Number = 0)
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function IsSafeDouble(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim result As Double
    result = CDbl(value) 'assigning value would be an undesirable side-effect here!
    IsSafeDouble = (Err.Number = 0)
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function IsSafeSingle(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim result As Single
    result = CSng(value) 'assigning value would be an undesirable side-effect here!
    IsSafeSingle = (Err.Number = 0)
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

---

This `IsTypeSafe` function is called by this code:

> ```vb
> Private Function ValidateItemType(value As Variant)
>
>    If this.ItemTypeName = vbNullString Then this.ItemTypeName = TypeName(value)
>    ValidateItemType = IsTypeSafe(value)
>
> End Function
> ```

Which is called whenever an item is tentatively added to the "type-safe" list:

> ```vb
> Public Sub Add(value As Variant)
> 'Adds an object to the end of the List.
>
>     If Not ValidateItemType(value) Then RaiseErrorUnsafeType "Add()", TypeName(value)
>
>     this.Encapsulated.Add value
>
> End Sub
> ```

This mechanism means the `List` is a `List<Variant>` until an item is added to it, and then if a `Smurf` instance is added, the list becomes a `List<Smurf>` and will fail to add anything other than a `Smurf` object.

---

Here's a little "test" method if you want to see the list in action:

```vb
Public Sub TestList()

    Dim lst As New List, tmp As List, i As Long

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    lst.Add 1, 2, 3, 4, 8

    Debug.Print lst.ToString & " contains " & lst.Count & " items:"
    GoSub EnumerateToDebugOutput

    lst.OptionStrict = False
    Debug.Print "OptionStrict = " & CStr(lst.OptionStrict)

    Debug.Print "OptionStrict set to FALSE should not allow overflow values:"
    Debug.Print lst.ToString & " can take value 32768? (" & TypeName(32768) & ") : " & lst.IsTypeSafe(32768)
    'lst.Add 32768

    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "OptionStrict set to FALSE should implicitly convert a value that can be safely converted to the type of the list:"
    On Error Resume Next
        Debug.Print "Adding value CByte(16)..."
        lst.Add CByte(16)
    On Error GoTo 0

    GoSub EnumerateToDebugOutput

    lst.OptionStrict = True
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "OptionStrict = " & CStr(lst.OptionStrict)
    Debug.Print "OptionStrict set to TRUE should not allow implicit conversion and throw an error if types mismatch:"

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Debug.Print "Adding value CByte(32)..."
    lst.Add CByte(32)

ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Number: " & Err.Number
        Debug.Print "Message: " & Err.Description
        Debug.Print "Source: " & Err.Source
        Debug.Print "Content:"
        GoSub EnumerateToDebugOutput

        Resume Next
    End If

    Exit Sub
EnumerateToDebugOutput:
    For i = 1 To lst.Count
        Debug.Print lst(i) & " (" & TypeName(lst(i)) & ")"
    Next
    Debug.Print

    Return

End Sub
```

...And the generated output:

```vb
TestList
List<Integer> contains 5 items:
1 (Integer)
2 (Integer)
3 (Integer)
4 (Integer)
8 (Integer)

OptionStrict = False
OptionStrict set to FALSE should not allow overflow values:
List<Integer> can take value 32768? (Long) : False

OptionStrict set to FALSE should implicitly convert a value that can be safely converted to the type of the list:
Adding value CByte(16)...
1 (Integer)
2 (Integer)
3 (Integer)
4 (Integer)
8 (Integer)
16 (Integer)


OptionStrict = True
OptionStrict set to TRUE should not allow implicit conversion and throw an error if types mismatch:
Adding value CByte(32)...
Number: -2147220503
Message: Type Mismatch. Expected: 'Integer', 'Byte' was supplied.
Source: List<Integer>.ValidateItemType()
Content:
1 (Integer)
2 (Integer)
3 (Integer)
4 (Integer)
8 (Integer)
16 (Integer)
```

Comment: reinventing the wheel a bit => the T is very limited though. Instead of all this work you could have used the [vb constants](http://vbadud.blogspot.co.uk/2007/04/get-variable-type.html) for types...

Comment: @mehow Good to see you over here! Feel free to post a review, +100 bounty ends in 4 days :)

Comment: not much to review in here except that if you press F2 in VBE and type `vbVarType` you get a list which you could possibly enumerate. That would replace the the select case statement and with a bit of error handling you can easily tell if type is *safe*

Comment: @mehow now you're making me say *if I only knew about these constants before...*

Comment: @mehow the T can be any type, including any object. That's handled in the first line of the `IsTypeSafe` method - returns true if type names match, the select case is just for edge cases where they don't. I'll see how I can use these constants but I'd love to see an answer that shows it (or I'll have to post my own implementation) :)

Comment: post your own:) as a tip consider a collection with enumerated constants-much easier to work with

Comment: @mehow, his code allows for conversion before returning whether the type is safe or not.  I think that is the reason why he would still need the case statement. if trying to input an object of a different type into the list then that might be a different story. but it looks like it will just return false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code looks very clean,

It looks like it handles edge cases well.

I especially like the way that if it converts to the specified data type that it does it and doesn't make you convert explicitly.  that is very slick!

I would definitely like to see some code that puts it into play.

Not much to review here, but very good code and good syntax.

**Edit**

I did find something that I might do differently.

Instead of `On Error Resume Next` 
I would make it more like a `Try Catch`

Perhaps something like this

```
Private Function IsSafeDate(value As Variant) As Boolean
'On Error Resume Next
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim result As Date
    result = CDate(value) 'assigning value would be an undesirable side-effect here!
    IsSafeDate = True   
    Exit Function    

ErrHandler:
    IsSafeDate = False
Err.Clear
End Function
```

I think this is a lot clearer as you are not really skating around the errors, and this way you can add an `Exit Sub` code too if you need it.

I like the `Try Catch` Method better myself.

Comment: I've added some "test code" with generated output :)

Comment: @retailcoder is there a way that I can run all that code somewhere nice and simple like so I can play with it a little bit? at work or on a linux machine?

Comment: It should work in VBA - try Excel (Alt+F11) :)

Comment: You'll have to simulate `this.TItem` if you don't want to copy the whole `List` class from the linked post. That said this linked post has all the code in an easy-copy format in revision 1 (see edit history).

Comment: So your answer is essentially that the `IsSafe[Type]` functions are not handling errors in a way that's consistent with the error handling code in the `IsTypeSafe` function (and the rest of the `List` class' code, for that matter) - and you're right! I guess I was just lazy... well sir, you've just earned yourself 100 rep points :)

Answer (score 1):

Just two nitpicks after years. :-)

Regarding the error handling in those `IsSafe...` procedures:

`Err.Clear` is superfluous there. It is called automatically when a procedure is exited.

The same goes for an enabled error handler, it will be disabled automatically when exiting a procedure, so `On Error GoTo 0` is not necessary there too.