# KeyValuePair implementation

Tags: vba, vb6

In order to implement my own `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` in VB6, I've implemented a `KeyValuePair` class, which can accomodate any type as its key, or value.

This `KeyValuePair` class implements the `IComparable` and `IEquatable` interfaces which I'm also using in [this custom `List<T>` implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/32618/23788)

#### KeyValuePair.cls

```vb
Private Type tKeyValuePair
    Key As Variant
    value As Variant
End Type

Private this As tKeyValuePair
Implements IComparable
Implements IEquatable
Option Explicit

Private Function IsComparable() As Boolean
    IsComparable = Not IsObject(this.Key) Or TypeOf this.Key Is IComparable
End Function

Public Property Get Key() As Variant
    If IsObject(this.Key) Then
        Set Key = this.Key
    Else
        Key = this.Key
    End If
End Property

Public Property Let Key(k As Variant)
    If IsEmpty(k) Then Err.Raise 5
    this.Key = k
End Property

Public Property Set Key(k As Variant)
    If IsEmpty(k) Then Err.Raise 5
    Set this.Key = k
End Property

Public Property Get value() As Variant
    If IsObject(this.value) Then
        Set value = this.value
    Else
        value = this.value
    End If
End Property

Public Property Let value(v As Variant)
    this.value = v
End Property

Public Property Set value(v As Variant)
    Set this.value = v
End Property

Public Function ToString() As String
    ToString = TypeName(Me) & "<" & TypeName(this.Key) & ", " & TypeName(this.value) & ">"
End Function

Private Function IComparable_CompareTo(other As Variant) As Integer
    
    Dim kvp As KeyValuePair
    Set kvp = other
    
    IComparable_CompareTo = ToString = kvp.ToString
    If Not IComparable_CompareTo Then Exit Function
    
    If IsObject(kvp.Key) Then
        IComparable_CompareTo = CompareReferenceTypes(this.Key, kvp.Key)
    Else
        IComparable_CompareTo = CompareValueTypes(this.Key, kvp.Key)
    End If
    
End Function

Private Function IEquatable_Equals(other As Variant) As Boolean
    
    Dim kvp As KeyValuePair
    Set kvp = other
    
    IEquatable_Equals = ToString = kvp.ToString
    If Not IEquatable_Equals Then Exit Function
    
    If IsObject(kvp.Key) Then
        IEquatable_Equals = EquateReferenceTypes(this.Key, kvp.Key)
    Else
        IEquatable_Equals = EquateValueTypes(this.Key, kvp.Key)
    End If
    
End Function

Private Function EquateReferenceTypes(value As Variant, other As Variant) As Boolean
    
    Dim equatable As IEquatable
    If IsObject(this.Key) And TypeOf this.Key Is IEquatable Then
        
        Set equatable = value
        EquateReferenceTypes = equatable.Equals(other)
        
    Else
        
        Debug.Print "WARNING: Reference type doesn't implement IEquatable, using reference equality."
        EquateReferenceTypes = (ObjPtr(value) = ObjPtr(other))
    
    End If
    
End Function

Private Function EquateValueTypes(value As Variant, other As Variant) As Boolean
    
    EquateValueTypes = (value = other)

End Function

Private Function CompareReferenceTypes(value As Variant, other As Variant) As Integer
    
    Dim comparable As IComparable
    
    If IsComparable Then
        
        Set comparable = value
        CompareReferenceTypes = comparable.CompareTo(other)
    
    Else
        
        Err.Raise 9 'object required
        Exit Function
        
    End If
    
End Function

Private Function CompareValueTypes(value As Variant, other As Variant) As Integer
    
    If value < other Then
        
        CompareValueTypes = -1
        
    ElseIf value > other Then
        
        CompareValueTypes = 1
        
    End If
    
End Function
```

In C#, a `KeyValuePair` is a `struct`, a value type - this implementation being a class, makes it analoguous to a *reference type*, are there any major drawbacks to this? If so, are there any viable alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That has been said before in previous reviews, there's not really a gain in having a `Private Type` that lets you define a `Private this As tKeyValuePair`, which forces you to use `this.` to access what would otherwise be private fields.

Actually there *is* one gain: doing that allows having a `Key` public member that encapsulates a `Key` private member, all without confusing poor old VB6 compiler.

Other than that, one has to see the `List` and possibly also the `Dictionary` implementation to see the benefits of the additional complexity introduced by `IEquatable` and `IComparable` interface implementations.

The code is fairly clean, straightforward and readable, breaking `IEquatable` and `IComparable` implementations into sub-functions respectively for reference and value types might be a little overboard, but it does make a nice abstraction level when one reads the implementation code.

One nitpick, the interface implementations and the corresponding sub-functions could declare a local `result` variable and assign the function's return value in only a single location:

```
Dim result As Boolean

If IsObject(kvp.Key) Then
    result = CompareReferenceTypes(this.Key, kvp.Key)
Else
    result = CompareValueTypes(this.Key, kvp.Key)
End If

IComparable_CompareTo = result
```

```
Dim result As Boolean

If IsObject(kvp.Key) Then
    result = EquateReferenceTypes(this.Key, kvp.Key)
Else
    result = EquateValueTypes(this.Key, kvp.Key)
End If

IEquatable_Equals = result
```

```
Dim result As Boolean
Dim equatable As IEquatable

If IsObject(this.Key) And TypeOf this.Key Is IEquatable Then
    Set equatable = value
    result = equatable.Equals(other)
Else
    Debug.Print "WARNING: Reference type doesn't implement IEquatable, using reference equality."
    result = (ObjPtr(value) = ObjPtr(other))
End If

EquateReferenceTypes = result
```

Looking more closely at the shape of the code, vertical whitespaces aren't all that consistent: there's more vertical whitespaces near the bottom of the code module, while the code near the top doesn't seem to follow the same spacing style. Minor nitpick, but for a small specialized class like this, it's an easy fix.