# Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Implementation

Tags: hash-map, vb6

This class encapsulates a `List<KeyValuePair>` (see `List<T>` implementation [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32618/listt-implementation-for-vb6-vba), and `KeyValuePair` implementation [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/45664/keyvaluepair-implementation)) and exposes a richer set of members than the typical `Scripting.Dictionary`, ..not to mention the anemic `Collection` class.

The class enforces some "type safety", in the sense that if you add a `KeyValuePair<String, Integer>`, then you'll only be allowed to add `KeyValuePair<String, Integer>` instances, the object will raise an error if you try adding, say, a `KeyValuePair<String, Control>`, or anything that's not a `KeyValuePair<String, Integer>`.

The `OptionStrict` property enables allowing more flexibility and adding a `KeyValuePair<String, Byte>` to a `Dictionary<String, Integer>`, for example (but not the opposite).

As with the `List<T>` implementation, this class uses *procedure attributes* (not shown) which make the `Item` property the default property (so `myDictionary(i)` returns the value at index `i`), and the `NewEnum` property enables iterating all values with a `For Each` loop construct.

```
Private Type tDictionary
    Encapsulated As List
    TKey As String
    IsRefTypeKey As Boolean
    TValue As String
    IsRefTypeValue As Boolean
End Type

Private Enum DictionaryErrors
    TypeMismatchUnsafeType = vbObjectError + 1001
End Enum

Private this As tDictionary
Option Explicit

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set this.Encapsulated = New List
    this.Encapsulated.OptionStrict = True
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set this.Encapsulated = Nothing
End Sub

Public Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = this.Encapsulated.Count
End Property

Public Property Get Keys() As List
    Dim result As New List
    Dim kvp As KeyValuePair

    result.OptionStrict = this.Encapsulated.OptionStrict

    For Each kvp In this.Encapsulated
        result.Add kvp.Key
    Next

    Set Keys = result
End Property

Public Property Get Values() As List
    Dim result As New List
    Dim kvp As KeyValuePair

    result.OptionStrict = this.Encapsulated.OptionStrict

    For Each kvp In this.Encapsulated
        result.Add kvp.value
    Next

    Set Values = result
End Property

Public Property Get OptionStrict() As Boolean
    OptionStrict = this.Encapsulated.OptionStrict
End Property

Public Property Let OptionStrict(value As Boolean)
    this.Encapsulated.OptionStrict = value
End Property

Private Function ToKeyValuePair(k As Variant, v As Variant) As KeyValuePair

    Dim result As New KeyValuePair
    If IsObject(k) Then
        Set result.Key = k
    Else
        result.Key = k
    End If

    If IsObject(v) Then
        Set result.value = v
    Else
        result.value = v
    End If

    Set ToKeyValuePair = result

End Function

Public Property Get Item(k As Variant) As Variant

    Dim i As Long
    i = Keys.IndexOf(k)

    If i = -1 Then Err.Raise 9 'index out of range
    If this.IsRefTypeValue Then
        Set Item = Values(i)
    Else
        Item = Values(i)
    End If

End Property

Public Property Set Item(k As Variant, v As Variant)

    Dim kvp As KeyValuePair
    Dim i As Long
    i = Keys.IndexOf(k)
    If i <> -1 Then

        Set kvp = ToKeyValuePair(k, v)
        Set this.Encapsulated(i) = kvp

    Else

        Add k, v

    End If

End Property

Public Property Let Item(k As Variant, v As Variant)

    Dim kvp As KeyValuePair
    Dim i As Long
    i = Keys.IndexOf(k)
    If i <> -1 Then

        Set kvp = ToKeyValuePair(k, v)
        Set this.Encapsulated(i) = kvp

    Else

        Add k, v

    End If

End Property

Public Sub Add(k As Variant, v As Variant)

    Dim kvp As KeyValuePair
    Set kvp = ToKeyValuePair(k, v)

    If Keys.Contains(k) Then Err.Raise 457 'key already exists

    If ValidateItemType(kvp, ThrowOnUnsafeType:=True) Then this.Encapsulated.Add kvp

End Sub

Private Function ValidateItemType(kvp As KeyValuePair, Optional ThrowOnUnsafeType As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    If this.TKey = vbNullString And this.TValue = vbNullString Then
        this.TKey = TypeName(kvp.Key)
        this.IsRefTypeKey = IsObject(kvp.Key)
        this.TValue = TypeName(kvp.value)
        this.IsRefTypeValue = IsObject(kvp.value)
    End If

    ValidateItemType = IsTypeSafe(kvp)

    If ThrowOnUnsafeType And Not ValidateItemType Then RaiseErrorUnsafeType "ValidateItemType()", kvp.ToString

End Function

Public Function IsTypeSafe(kvp As KeyValuePair) As Boolean
'Determines whether a value can be safely added to the List.

    IsTypeSafe = (this.TKey = vbNullString Or this.TKey = TypeName(kvp.Key)) _
             And (this.TValue = vbNullString Or this.TValue = TypeName(kvp.value))
    If IsTypeSafe Then Exit Function

    Select Case this.TKey

        Case "String":
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeKeyString(kvp.Key)
            If IsTypeSafe Then kvp.Key = CStr(kvp.Key)

        Case "Boolean"
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeKeyBoolean(kvp.Key)
            If IsTypeSafe Then kvp.Key = CBool(kvp.Key)

        Case "Byte":
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeKeyByte(kvp.Key)
            If IsTypeSafe Then kvp.Key = CByte(kvp.Key)

        Case "Date":
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeKeyDate(kvp.Key)
            If IsTypeSafe Then kvp.Key = CDate(kvp.Key)

        Case "Integer":
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeKeyInteger(kvp.Key)
            If IsTypeSafe Then kvp.Key = CInt(kvp.Key)

        Case "Long":
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeKeyLong(kvp.Key)
            If IsTypeSafe Then kvp.Key = CLng(kvp.Key)

        Case "Single"
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeKeySingle(kvp.Key)
            If IsTypeSafe Then kvp.Key = CSng(kvp.Key)

        Case "Double":
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeKeyDouble(kvp.Key)
            If IsTypeSafe Then kvp.Key = CDbl(kvp.Key)

        Case "Currency":
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeKeyCurrency(kvp.Key)
            If IsTypeSafe Then kvp.Key = CCur(kvp.Key)

        Case Else:
            IsTypeSafe = False

    End Select

    If Not IsTypeSafe Then Exit Function

    Select Case this.TValue

        Case "String":
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeValueString(kvp.value)
            If IsTypeSafe Then kvp.value = CStr(kvp.value)

        Case "Boolean"
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeValueBoolean(kvp.value)
            If IsTypeSafe Then kvp.value = CBool(kvp.value)

        Case "Byte":
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeValueByte(kvp.value)
            If IsTypeSafe Then kvp.value = CByte(kvp.value)

        Case "Date":
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeValueDate(kvp.value)
            If IsTypeSafe Then kvp.value = CDate(kvp.value)

        Case "Integer":
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeValueInteger(kvp.value)
            If IsTypeSafe Then kvp.value = CInt(kvp.value)

        Case "Long":
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeValueLong(kvp.value)
            If IsTypeSafe Then kvp.value = CLng(kvp.value)

        Case "Single"
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeValueSingle(kvp.value)
            If IsTypeSafe Then kvp.value = CSng(kvp.value)

        Case "Double":
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeValueDouble(kvp.value)
            If IsTypeSafe Then kvp.value = CDbl(kvp.value)

        Case "Currency":
            IsTypeSafe = IsSafeValueCurrency(kvp.value)
            If IsTypeSafe Then kvp.value = CCur(kvp.value)

        Case Else:
            IsTypeSafe = False

    End Select


ErrHandler:
    'swallow overflow errors:
    If Err.number = 6 Then
        Err.Clear
        Resume Next
    ElseIf Err.number <> 0 Then
        RaiseErrorUnsafeType "IsTypeSafe()", kvp.ToString
    End If

End Function

Private Function IsSafeKeyString(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeKeyString = (this.TKey = vbNullString Or this.TKey = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeKeyString Or OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CStr(value)
    IsSafeKeyString = (Err.number = 0)
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function IsSafeKeyDate(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeKeyDate = (this.TKey = vbNullString Or this.TKey = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeKeyDate Or OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CDate(value)
    IsSafeKeyDate = (Err.number = 0)
    'If this.OptionTrace And IsSafeKeyString(Value) Then Debug.Print "TRACE: IsSafeKeyDate(" & CStr(Value) & ") : " & IsSafeKeyDate
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function IsSafeKeyByte(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeKeyByte = (this.TKey = vbNullString Or this.TKey = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeKeyByte Or OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CByte(value)
    IsSafeKeyByte = (Err.number = 0)
    'If this.OptionTrace And IsSafeKeyString(Value) Then Debug.Print "TRACE: IsSafeKeyByte(" & CStr(Value) & ") : " & IsSafeKeyByte
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function IsSafeKeyBoolean(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeKeyBoolean = (this.TKey = vbNullString Or this.TKey = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeKeyBoolean Or OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CBool(value)
    IsSafeKeyBoolean = (Err.number = 0)
    'If this.OptionTrace And IsSafeKeyString(Value) Then Debug.Print "TRACE: IsSafeKeyBoolean(" & CStr(Value) & ") : " & IsSafeKeyBoolean

    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function IsSafeKeyCurrency(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeKeyCurrency = (this.TKey = vbNullString Or this.TKey = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeKeyCurrency Or OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CCur(value)
    IsSafeKeyCurrency = (Err.number = 0)
    'If this.OptionTrace And IsSafeKeyString(Value) Then Debug.Print "TRACE: IsSafeKeyCurrency(" & CStr(Value) & ") : " & IsSafeKeyCurrency
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function IsSafeKeyInteger(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeKeyInteger = (this.TKey = vbNullString Or this.TKey = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeKeyInteger Or OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CInt(value)
    IsSafeKeyInteger = (Err.number = 0)
    'If this.OptionTrace And IsSafeKeyString(Value) Then Debug.Print "TRACE: IsSafeKeyInteger(" & CStr(Value) & ") : " & IsSafeKeyInteger
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function IsSafeKeyLong(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeKeyLong = (this.TKey = vbNullString Or this.TKey = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeKeyLong Or OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CLng(value)
    IsSafeKeyLong = (Err.number = 0)
    'If this.OptionTrace And IsSafeKeyString(Value) Then Debug.Print "TRACE: IsSafeKeyLong(" & CStr(Value) & ") : " & IsSafeKeyLong
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function IsSafeKeyDouble(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeKeyDouble = (this.TKey = vbNullString Or this.TKey = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeKeyDouble Or OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CDbl(value)
    IsSafeKeyDouble = (Err.number = 0)
    'If this.OptionTrace And IsSafeKeyString(Value) Then Debug.Print "TRACE: IsSafeKeyDouble(" & CStr(Value) & ") : " & IsSafeKeyDouble
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function IsSafeKeySingle(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeKeySingle = (this.TKey = vbNullString Or this.TKey = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeKeySingle Or OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CSng(value)
    IsSafeKeySingle = (Err.number = 0)
    'If this.OptionTrace And IsSafeKeyString(Value) Then Debug.Print "TRACE: IsSafeKeySingle(" & CStr(Value) & ") : " & IsSafeKeySingle
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function IsSafeValueString(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeValueString = (this.TValue = vbNullString Or this.TValue = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeValueString Or OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CStr(value)
    IsSafeValueString = (Err.number = 0)
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function IsSafeValueDate(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeValueDate = (this.TValue = vbNullString Or this.TValue = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeValueDate Or OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CDate(value)
    IsSafeValueDate = (Err.number = 0)
    'If this.OptionTrace And IsSafeValueString(Value) Then Debug.Print "TRACE: IsSafeValueDate(" & CStr(Value) & ") : " & IsSafeValueDate
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function IsSafeValueByte(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeValueByte = (this.TValue = vbNullString Or this.TValue = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeValueByte Or OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CByte(value)
    IsSafeValueByte = (Err.number = 0)
    'If this.OptionTrace And IsSafeValueString(Value) Then Debug.Print "TRACE: IsSafeValueByte(" & CStr(Value) & ") : " & IsSafeValueByte
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function IsSafeValueBoolean(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeValueBoolean = (this.TValue = vbNullString Or this.TValue = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeValueBoolean Or OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CBool(value)
    IsSafeValueBoolean = (Err.number = 0)
    'If this.OptionTrace And IsSafeValueString(Value) Then Debug.Print "TRACE: IsSafeValueBoolean(" & CStr(Value) & ") : " & IsSafeValueBoolean

    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function IsSafeValueCurrency(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeValueCurrency = (this.TValue = vbNullString Or this.TValue = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeValueCurrency Or OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CCur(value)
    IsSafeValueCurrency = (Err.number = 0)
    'If this.OptionTrace And IsSafeValueString(Value) Then Debug.Print "TRACE: IsSafeValueCurrency(" & CStr(Value) & ") : " & IsSafeValueCurrency
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function IsSafeValueInteger(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeValueInteger = (this.TValue = vbNullString Or this.TValue = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeValueInteger Or OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CInt(value)
    IsSafeValueInteger = (Err.number = 0)
    'If this.OptionTrace And IsSafeValueString(Value) Then Debug.Print "TRACE: IsSafeValueInteger(" & CStr(Value) & ") : " & IsSafeValueInteger
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function IsSafeValueLong(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeValueLong = (this.TValue = vbNullString Or this.TValue = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeValueLong Or OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CLng(value)
    IsSafeValueLong = (Err.number = 0)
    'If this.OptionTrace And IsSafeValueString(Value) Then Debug.Print "TRACE: IsSafeValueLong(" & CStr(Value) & ") : " & IsSafeValueLong
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function IsSafeValueDouble(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeValueDouble = (this.TValue = vbNullString Or this.TValue = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeValueDouble Or OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CDbl(value)
    IsSafeValueDouble = (Err.number = 0)
    'If this.OptionTrace And IsSafeValueString(Value) Then Debug.Print "TRACE: IsSafeValueDouble(" & CStr(Value) & ") : " & IsSafeValueDouble
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function IsSafeValueSingle(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeValueSingle = (this.TValue = vbNullString Or this.TValue = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeValueSingle Or OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CSng(value)
    IsSafeValueSingle = (Err.number = 0)
    'If this.OptionTrace And IsSafeValueString(Value) Then Debug.Print "TRACE: IsSafeValueSingle(" & CStr(Value) & ") : " & IsSafeValueSingle
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function



Private Sub RaiseErrorUnsafeType(member As String, suppliedType As String)
    Err.Raise DictionaryErrors.TypeMismatchUnsafeType, _
                StringFormat("{0}.{1}", ToString, member), _
                StringFormat("Type Mismatch. Expected: 'KeyValuePair<{0},{1}>', '{2}' was supplied.", this.TKey, this.TValue, suppliedType)
End Sub

Public Sub Clear()
    this.Encapsulated.Clear
End Sub

Public Function Contains(v As Variant) As Boolean
    Contains = Values.Contains(v)
End Function

Public Function ContainsKey(k As Variant) As Boolean
    ContainsKey = Keys.Contains(k)
End Function

Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
'Gets an enumerator that iterates through the values held in the Dictionary.

    Set NewEnum = this.Encapsulated.NewEnum

End Property

Public Function Remove(v As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim i As Long
    i = Values.IndexOf(v)

    If i <> -1 Then

        this.Encapsulated.RemoveAt i
        Remove = True

    Else

        Remove = False

    End If

End Function

Public Function RemoveKey(k As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim i As Long
    i = Keys.IndexOf(k)

    If i <> -1 Then

        this.Encapsulated.RemoveAt i
        RemoveKey = True

    Else

        RemoveKey = False

    End If

End Function

Public Function TryGetValue(k As Variant, ByRef outValue As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim i As Long
    i = Keys.IndexOf(k)

    Dim kvp As KeyValuePair
    If i <> -1 Then

        Set kvp = this.Encapsulated(i)
        If IsObject(kvp.value) Then
            Set outValue = kvp.value
        Else
            outValue = kvp.value
        End If

        TryGetValue = True

    Else

        TryGetValue = False

    End If

End Function

Public Function ToList() As List
    Set ToList = this.Encapsulated
End Function

Public Function ToString() As String
    ToString = TypeName(Me) & "<" & IIf(this.TKey = vbNullString, "Variant", this.TKey) & ", " & IIf(this.TValue = vbNullString, "Variant", this.TValue) & ">"
End Function
```

I've written this a little while ago, in the mean time I've learned about `CallByName`, so now I wonder if there wouldn't be a really clever way to rework the `IsTypeSafe` method so as to avoid the `Select Case` blocks (`CallByName` doesn't seem to work for functions / methods with a return value).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although `CallByName` doesn't seem to have a return value (from the parameter tooltip), it does. This means if `IsSafeKeyXxxxxx` methods were `Public` you could use `CallByName` instead of the `Select..Case` block.

However exposing all these methods through your `Dictionary` interface would be rather ugly. How about extracting all these small methods into their own `TypeValidator` class?

```
Private Type tValueTypeValidator
    TValue As String
    OptionStrict As Boolean
End Type

Private this As tValueTypeValidator
Option Explicit

Public Property Get TValue() As String
    TValue = this.TValue
End Property

Public Property Let TValue(ByVal value As String)
    this.TValue = value
End Property

Public Property Get OptionStrict() As Boolean
    OptionStrict = this.OptionStrict
End Property

Public Property Let OptionStrict(ByVal value As Boolean)
    this.OptionStrict = value
End Property

Public Function ToString() As String
    ToString = TypeName(Me) & "<" & this.TValue & ">"
End Function

Public Function IsSafeBoolean(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeBoolean = (this.TValue = vbNullString Or this.TValue = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeBoolean Or this.OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CBool(value)
    IsSafeBoolean = (Err.Number = 0)

    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Function IsSafeByte(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeByte = (this.TValue = vbNullString Or this.TValue = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeByte Or this.OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CByte(value)
    IsSafeByte = (Err.Number = 0)

    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Function IsSafeCurrency(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeCurrency = (this.TValue = vbNullString Or this.TValue = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeCurrency Or this.OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CCur(value)
    IsSafeCurrency = (Err.Number = 0)

    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Function IsSafeDate(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeDate = (this.TValue = vbNullString Or this.TValue = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeDate Or this.OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CDate(value)
    IsSafeDate = (Err.Number = 0)

    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Function IsSafeDouble(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeDouble = (this.TValue = vbNullString Or this.TValue = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeDouble Or this.OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CDbl(value)
    IsSafeDouble = (Err.Number = 0)

    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Function IsSafeInteger(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeInteger = (this.TValue = vbNullString Or this.TValue = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeInteger Or this.OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CInt(value)
    IsSafeInteger = (Err.Number = 0)

    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Function IsSafeLong(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeLong = (this.TValue = vbNullString Or this.TValue = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeLong Or OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CLng(value)
    IsSafeLong = (Err.Number = 0)

    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Function IsSafeSingle(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeSingle = (this.TValue = vbNullString Or this.TValue = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeSingle Or this.OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CSng(value)
    IsSafeSingle = (Err.Number = 0)

    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Function IsSafeString(value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    IsSafeString = (this.TValue = vbNullString Or this.TValue = TypeName(value))
    If IsSafeString Or this.OptionStrict Then Exit Function

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = CStr(value)
    IsSafeString = (Err.Number = 0)
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

And since that code was copy-pasted from an existing `List` class in the first place, there's already a case for reusing that `TypeValidator` class.

That change would require the `ValidateItemType` method to be modified as such:

```
Private Function ValidateItemType(kvp As KeyValuePair, Optional ThrowOnUnsafeType As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    If this.TKey = vbNullString And this.TValue = vbNullString Then
        this.TKey = TypeName(kvp.key)
        this.IsRefTypeKey = IsObject(kvp.key)
        this.TValue = TypeName(kvp.value)
        this.IsRefTypeValue = IsObject(kvp.value)
        this.KeyValidator.TValue = this.TKey '<<< here
        this.ValueValidator.TValue = this.TValue '<<< here
    End If

    ValidateItemType = IsTypeSafe(kvp)

    If ThrowOnUnsafeType And Not ValidateItemType Then RaiseErrorUnsafeType "ValidateItemType()", kvp.ToString

End Function
```

The `OptionStrict` property setter would have to be affected as well:

```
Public Property Let OptionStrict(value As Boolean)
    this.Encapsulated.OptionStrict = value
    this.KeyValidator.OptionStrict = value ' <<< here
    this.ValueValidator.OptionStrict = value ' <<< here
End Property
```

As well as the `Class_Initialize` method:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set this.Encapsulated = New List
    Set this.KeyValidator = New TypeValidator ' <<< here
    Set this.ValueValidator = New TypeValidator ' <<< here
    this.Encapsulated.OptionStrict = True
    this.KeyValidator.OptionStrict = True ' <<< here
    this.ValueValidator.OptionStrict = True ' <<< here
End Sub
```

And of course the private type of `this`:

```
Private Type tDictionary
    Encapsulated As List
    TKey As String
    IsRefTypeKey As Boolean
    TValue As String
    IsRefTypeValue As Boolean
    KeyValidator As TypeValidator ' <<< here
    ValueValidator As TypeValidator ' <<< here
End Type
```

The `IsTypeSafe` method implementation could then be simplified to this - gone, the `Select..Case` blocks!

```
Public Function IsTypeSafe(kvp As KeyValuePair) As Boolean
'Determines whether a value can be safely added to the List.

    IsTypeSafe = (this.TKey = vbNullString Or this.TKey = TypeName(kvp.key)) _
             And (this.TValue = vbNullString Or this.TValue = TypeName(kvp.value))
    If IsTypeSafe Then Exit Function

    IsTypeSafe = CallByName(this.KeyValidator, "IsSafe" & this.TKey, VbMethod, kvp.key)
    If Not IsTypeSafe Then Exit Function

    IsTypeSafe = CallByName(this.ValueValidator, "IsSafe" & this.TValue, VbMethod, kvp.value)

ErrHandler:
    'swallow overflow errors:
    If Err.Number = 6 Then
        Err.Clear
        Resume Next
    ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 Then
        RaiseErrorUnsafeType "IsTypeSafe()", kvp.ToString
    End If
End Function
```

This also leaves you with a much, much cleaner list of members, as a side-effect of separating the type validation concerns into their own class:

[image: Members of Dictionary]
[image: Members of TypeValidator]

<sub>Busted! Yes, I work with a French VB6 IDE!</sub>