# Ranking a variant array with variable dimensions

Tags: array, unit-testing, vba

I'm doing VBA macros and need to use Arrays of values extensively. After the below help from @TonyDallimore on Stack Overflow, I've decided to use nested variant arrays.

[VBA chrashes when trying to execute generated sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971161/vba-chrashes-when-trying-to-execute-generated-sub/20973615#20973615)

I use multidimensional, jagged arrays to `SELECT` data from DB's and efficiently perform calculations and write to a Worksheet. The data is sometimes a single value ([Rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(computer_programming)):0) sometimes a row of values (Rank:1) sometimes a table of values with some cells containing rows of values (Rank:3). I use the function below to determine what kind of operations are possible and should be performed to such arrays.

This function, along with all my array related functions reside in a module: modCustomArrayFunctions.

```
'***************************************************************************'
'Returns the rank of the passed array                                       '
'Parameters:                                                                '
'   Arr: The array to be processed                                          '
'Returns:                                                                   '
'   The rank of the array                                                   '
'***************************************************************************'
Public Function Rank(ByRef Arr As Variant) As Byte
'Declarations **************************************************************'
Dim MaxRank As Byte     'Maximum rank of the elements of the array          '
Dim i As Integer
'***************************************************************************'
    If IsArray(Arr) Then
        If IsArrInitialized(Arr) Then
            MaxRank = 0
            For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
                Rank = Rank(Arr(i)) + 1
                If Rank > MaxRank Then MaxRank = Rank
            Next i
            Rank = MaxRank
        Else
            Rank = 0
        End If
    Else
        Rank = 0
    End If
End Function
'***************************************************************************'
```

I code my routines pretty much this way.

And the accompanying test is as follows:

```
'***************************************************************************'
Public Sub Rank_Test()
Dim TestArr As Variant
Dim TestRank As Integer
    'Test Non-Array
    If Rank(TestArr) = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Non-Array OK"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Non-Array FAILED!"
    End If

    'Test Ranks 1 to 100
    For TestRank = 1 To 100
        TestArr = MakeArray(TestRank)
        If Rank(TestArr) = TestRank Then
            Debug.Print TestRank & "D OK"
        Else
            Debug.Print TestRank & "D FAILED!"
        End If
    Next TestRank
End Sub
'***************************************************************************'
```

Can the code, comments and test be deemed acceptable, what is there to improve?
Is the test okay or have I got the whole unit testing idea wrong?

`IsArrInitialized()` and `MakeArray(n)` are listed for completeness here. Note that `MakeArray(n)` is only used to create test arrays and is private to the array test module.

```
'***************************************************************************'
Private Function MakeArray( _
    RankArr As Integer, _
    Optional Value As Variant = 1 _
) As Variant
Dim TestArr As Variant
Dim DummyArr As Variant
Dim i As Integer
    If RankArr = 0 Then
        MakeArray = Value
    ElseIf RankArr = 1 Then
        ReDim TestArr(1 To 1)
        TestArr(1) = Value
        MakeArray = TestArr
    Else
        ReDim TestArr(1 To 1)
        ReDim DummyArr(1 To 1)
        DummyArr(1) = Value
        For i = 1 To RankArr - 1
            DoEvents
            TestArr(1) = DummyArr
            DummyArr = TestArr
        Next i
        MakeArray = TestArr
    End If
End Function
'***************************************************************************'
```

---

```
'***************************************************************************'
'Determines if a dynamic array has been initialized                         '
'Parameters:                                                                '
'   Arr: The array to be processed                                          '
'Returns:                                                                   '
'   True if initialized, False if not                                       '
'***************************************************************************'
Public Function IsArrInitialized(ByRef Arr As Variant) As Boolean
'Declarations **************************************************************'
Dim dum As Long
'***************************************************************************'
    On Error GoTo ErrLine
    If IsArray(Arr) Then
        dum = LBound(Arr)
        If dum > UBound(Arr) Then
            GoTo ErrLine
        Else
            IsArrInitialized = True
        End If
    Else
        IsArrInitialized = False
    End If
Exit Function
ErrLine:
    IsArrInitialized = False
End Function
'***************************************************************************'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the not-listed `IsArrInitialized`, after investigating on StackOverflow, I ended up using this:

```
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
                               (pDst As Any, pSrc As Any, ByVal ByteLen As Long)

'returns true if specified array is initialized.
Public Function IsArrayInitialized(arr) As Boolean

  Dim memVal As Long

  CopyMemory memVal, ByVal VarPtr(arr) + 8, ByVal 4 'get pointer to array
  CopyMemory memVal, ByVal memVal, ByVal 4  'see if it points to an address...
  IsArrayInitialized = (memVal <> 0)        '...if it does, array is intialized

End Function
```

I would love to see your `MakeArray` implementation, but I'll stick to the `Rank` function.

#### Comments

```
'***************************************************************************'
'Returns the rank of the passed array                                       '
'Parameters:                                                                '
'   Arr: The array to be processed                                          '
'Returns:                                                                   '
'   The rank of the array                                                   '
'***************************************************************************'
```

I remember being told, in school, that this was a good way of documenting code. However, real-world experience has proven otherwise. These comments only clutter up the code, add to the burden of maintenance and inevitably become stale/obsolete/lies.

What's the need exactly? *Say what the thing does*. Good, useful comments don't do that - the *code itself* says "what", good comments say "why". How do you know what the thing does? With proper encapsulation and naming!

If the `Rank` function is defined in a code module called `Helpers.bas` that contains dozens of unrelated specialized functions like this, you have a problem. If it's defined in a code module called `ArrayHelpers.bas` that contains dozens of somewhat related specifalized functions like this, you have a lesser problem, but a problem still: in VBA anything `Public` declared in a code module (.bas) is accessible as a "macro" - a `Public Function` in Excel VBA could even be used as a cell formula, so naming is very important to avoid clashes with existing/"native" functions.

```
'Declarations **************************************************************'
```

Please don't. If you feel the need to "sectionize" the code inside a function, chances are that function is doing too many things.

```
Dim MaxRank As Byte     'Maximum rank of the elements of the array
```

These comments shouldn't be needed; it should be clear what `MaxRank` is used for, and if it isn't, then the identifier needs a better name, not a comment.

---

#### Naming

I think `Rank` is a poor name for what the function does. First, I'm tempted to read it as a *verb*, but you intend it as a *noun* - nouns are generally *classes* (/objects), and verbs are for *methods*, *functions* and *procedures*.

#### Readability

Your function is recursive, and it's not clear what the intent is - arrays have *indices*, not "ranks" - the multiple assignments of the function's return value are also a hinderance, consider this:

```
Public Function Rank(ByRef Arr As Variant) As Byte
    Dim Result As Byte
    Dim MaxRank As Byte
    Dim i As Integer

    If IsArray(Arr) Then
        If IsArrInitialized(Arr) Then

            MaxRank = 0

            For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
                Result = Rank(Arr(i)) + 1 ' recursive call
                If Result > MaxRank Then MaxRank = Result
            Next i

            Result = MaxRank

        Else
            Result = 0
        End If
    Else
        Result = 0
    End If

    Rank = Result
End Function
```

The function's return value being only assigned once, makes it easier to rename it and easier to read and tell the reads from the writes and recursive calls at a glance.

#### Bug?

Unless you've specified [`Option Base 1` VBA arrays are 0-based](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266179(v=vs.60).aspx), which means a return value of 0 could be problematic. Typical VBA code would return -1 for an invalid index, so you can tell an invalid index from a zero-based first index.

This, of course, is countered by explicitly declaring the lower bound of your arrays `(1 to 1, 1 to 1, 1 to n)`, but that's a rather verbose way of declaring an array.

---

That said, I'm not 100% clear on exactly what that function is achieving, even after reading your SO post. Is it possible that you don't *really* need a multidimensional array (1,1,n), but rather a list of objects that encapsulate an array and two other fields? [This code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32618/listt-implementation-for-vb6-vba) could be of interest.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough review. I will definitely keep your points in mind when I revise this and write new code. I tend to use too much comments, I know and this is due to the fact that a DBA with little xp in programming will have to maintain, while I'm away for some months. A return value of 0 would actually mean that the variant is actually a single value and not an array. I added the missing functions and also stated my motivation to use such a function.

Answer (score 3):

From above:

> you have a lesser problem, but a problem still: in VBA anything Public declared in a code module (.bas) is accessible as a "macro" - a Public Function in Excel VBA could even be used as a cell formula, so naming is very important to avoid clashes with existing/"native" functions.

To keep your internal public subs and functions from appearing in the user macro list, define them with an optional parameter, even though it is never used.

```
Public Sub YourName(Optional Dummy As Variant = Nothing)
    ' Your code goes here.
End Sub
```

Comment: Dummy arguments? **NO!** Terrible practice. There is literally an in-built option for this, `Option Private Module`.