# VBA Python-like List Class

Tags: vba

VBA's `Collection` class is lacking so I created a basic `List` class using Python's as a template.  This could make future derived classes easier to implement.

The biggest features are better setting and accessing of values. But one neat-o feature is Python-style indexing.

```
Dim myList As List
myList.Extend(Array(1,2,3,4,5,6))
Debug.Print myList(-2) ' 5
Debug.print myList.Slice(-1, 1).ToString '"[6,5,4,3,2,1]"
```

Note: I kept VBA's 1 offset for collections.  This means that there is a hole at index 0 and will always return *subscript out of range*.  I don't like it but this way List's will play nice with VBA's collection objects.

### Private members

```
Option Explicit
Private collec As Collection ' Sole datamember
```

`TransformIndex`: Enforces Zero Offset and Cylcing.

```
Private Sub TransformIndex(ByRef x As Variant)
    If x < 0 Then x = x + collec.Count + 1
End Sub
```

Replace is `private`; use `Item` and `Slice` to actually replace elements

```
Private Sub Replace(ByVal index As Long, ByVal element As Variant)

    collec.Remove index

    If index = collec.Count + 1 Then
        collec.Add element
    Else
        collec.Add element, before:=index
    End If

End Sub
```

Some boring stuff

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set collec = New Collection
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set collec = Nothing
End Sub
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4

    Set NewEnum = collec.[_NewEnum]

End Property
```

### Public Methods

The general pattern for these is and implementation of one action for a single element and another for a sequence of elements.  *e.g.* `Item` and then `Slice` or `Append` and `Extend`.  The only exception is removal that only implements single elements.

#### Accessers and Replacement

`Item` and `Slice` provide general access to members and allows replacement as they are not read only.

```
Public Property Let Item(ByVal index As Long, ByVal element As Variant)
Attribute Item.VB_UserMemId = 0

    TransformIndex index
    Replace index, element

End Property
Public Property Set Item(ByVal index As Long, ByVal element As Variant)
Attribute Item.VB_UserMemId = 0

    TransformIndex index
    Replace index, element

End Property
```

`seq` is an auxiliary module for general sequence functions. For purposes of this review assume functions from it does exactly what it should do. `seq.Assign(x,y)` assign's or sets `x` to `y`.

```
Public Property Get Item(ByVal index As Long) As Variant
Attribute Item.VB_UserMemId = 0

    TransformIndex index
    seq.Assign Item, collec.Item(index)

End Property
```

`Slice`: Allows for accessing sub sequences from `a` to `b`. Regardless of the order.  You can specify a step `s` to skip elements but note that `s` must be a natural number.  If you want to get a reversed sequence make `b` less than `a` not a negative `s`.

Also `Slice` is read-write, so it allows replacement of sub-sequences.

```
Public Property Get Slice(ByVal a As Long, ByVal b As Long, Optional ByVal s As Long = 1) As List

    TransformIndex a
    TransformIndex b

    Set Slice = New List

    If s < 1 Then Err.Raise "List.Slice", "Step " & s & " is not a natural number."
    s = IIF(a < b, s, -s)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = a To b Step s
        Slice.Append collec.Item(i)
    Next i

End Property
Public Property Let Slice(ByVal a As Long, ByVal b As Long, Optional ByVal s As Long = 1, ByVal sequence As Variant)

    TransformIndex a
    TransformIndex b

    If s < 1 Then Err.Raise "List.Slice", "Step " & s & " is not a natural number."
    s = IIF(a < b, s, -s)

    If Abs(a - b) + 1 <> seq.Length(sequence) Then
        Err.Raise 9, "List.Slice", "Subscript out of Range."
    End If

    Dim i As Long: i = a
    Dim element As Variant
    For Each element In sequence

        Replace i, element
        i = i + s

    Next element

    Debug.Assert (i - s = b)

End Property
```

#### Removal Methods

```
Public Sub Remove(ByVal index As Long)

    TransformIndex index
    collec.Remove index

End Sub
''
' List.Clear(x, y) \equiv List.Clear(y, x)
Public Sub Clear(ByVal a As Long, ByVal b As Long)

    TransformIndex a
    TransformIndex b
    ' Order of removal is irrelevant
    If a > b Then seq.Swap a, b

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To b - a
        collec.Remove a
    Next i

End Sub
```

<strike>I have been trying to work out a `RemoveRange` function.  I will update with them later.</strike> Added a `Clear` function.  Note `List.Clear(x, y)` \$ \equiv \$ `List.Clear(y, x)`.

#### Appending Methods

```
Public Sub Append(ByVal element As Variant)
    collec.Add element
End Sub
Public Sub Extend(ByVal sequence As Variant)

    Dim element As Variant
    For Each element In sequence
        collec.Add element
    Next element

End Sub
```

#### Insertion Methods

```
Public Sub Emplace(ByVal index As Long, ByVal element As Variant)

    TransformIndex index
    collec.Add element, before:=index

End Sub
Public Sub Insert(ByVal index As Long, ByVal sequence As Variant)

    TransformIndex index
    seq.Reverse sequence

    Dim element As Variant
    For Each element In sequence
        collec.Add element, before:=index
    Next element

End Sub
```

#### Auxiliary Methods

```
Public Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = collec.Count
End Property
Public Function Exists(ByVal sought As Variant) As Boolean

    Exists = True

    Dim element As Variant
    For Each element In collec
        If element = sought Then Exit Function
    Next element

    Exists = False

End Function
Public Property Get ToString() As String
    ToString = "[" & Join(seq.ToArray(collec), ", ") & "]"
End Property
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm no VBA coder so just a few minor things:

1. Is there a particular reason to use `ByRef` for the parameter to `TransformIndex`? It doesn't seem exactly necessary and I usually prefer methods without side effects.
2. `collec` reads clumsy. I would rename it to something like `underlying` or `underlyingCollection`.
3. You should take a bit more care naming method parameters. Parameter names form an important part of the method documentation and should convey their intent clearly. For example here it is not exactly clear what `a` and `b` mean:

   > ```
   > Public Sub Clear(ByVal a As Long, ByVal b As Long)
   > ```
4. For `Clear` it is not entirely clear if for example the end index is included or not for the removal. C# usually follows the convention of specify the start index and the count of how many elements should be removed (i.e. `Clear(start, count)`). I found that approach more robust in the long run.
5. I don't think dumping the entire list content in `ToString()` is all that useful, especially if the list can grow larger it could be problematic.

Comment: My rational for using `ByRef` for `TransformIndex` was that the alternative was to make it a function, but then it would look like `index = TransformIndex(index)`, which seems redundant.  Otherwise great points, especially `Clear(start, count)`.

Answer (score 4):

Only a a couple of minor notes. It looks pretty good (but admittedly, I've not run the code).

1. Single letter argument names obfuscate their meaning.

   > ```
   > Public Property Get Slice(ByVal a As Long, ByVal b As Long, Optional ByVal s As Long = 1) As List
   > ```
2. I find it a little odd to initialize a bool to true, then set it to false if the code doesn't exit early. I would rewrite your `Exists` method just a little bit.

   ```
   Public Function Exists(ByVal sought As Variant) As Boolean

       Dim element As Variant
       For Each element In collec
           If element = sought Then 
               Exists = True
               Exit Function
           End If
       Next element

       Exists = False

   End Function
   ```

   It's semantically the same, but the intent is a little clearer IMO.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what was already said, I'll add these points:

> ```
> Public Sub Extend(ByVal sequence As Variant)
>
>     Dim element As Variant
>     For Each element In sequence
>         collec.Add element
>     Next element
>
> End Sub
> ```

Here the only clue the calling code has about the expected type, is the parameter's name (`sequence`) - that reinforces what was already said about meaningful parameter names, but I find the way you've implemented this forces the client to add boilerplate code just to be able to pass values to this method.

A much more convenient (and self-documenting) way of taking in an arbitrary number of parameters, is to use a `ParamArray`, and iterate its indices instead:

```
Public Sub Extend(ParamArray items())

    Dim i As Integer
    For i LBound(items) To UBound(items)
        collec.Add items(i)
    Next

End Sub
```

That way the client code can do this:

```
Dim myList As New List
myList.Extend 12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67, "bob", 98.99
```

Notice a VBA `Collection` doesn't enforce any kind of type safety, so the item at index 1 could be a `String` while the item at index 2 could be a `Double`, or even an `Object` of any given type.

I know nothing of [python](/questions/tagged/python), so maybe that isn't an issue, but if your list is meant to only contain one type of items, you have a problem here.

Speaking of which:

> ```
> Public Property Get ToString() As String
>     ToString = "[" & Join(seq.ToArray(collec), ", ") & "]"
> End Property
> ```

I don't see `seq.ToArray` anywhere, but whatever it's doing, it's not accounting for the fact that your `List` can take `Object` items, and doing that would break your `ToString` implementation, while every other method would seemingly work as expected. You should verify whether an item `IsObject` before attempting to do something with it that wouldn't work on an object.

You might have seen [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32618), where I solved these issues in a .net-type `List<T>` (although my `ToString` doesn't list the contents).

Comment: I don't see how `ParamArray` is a functional solution.  It prevents the client from extending a `List` with another `List` or any other iterable.  The only benefit is the syntactic sugar for initialization of not wrapping the args in `Array(`.  -- Also a `TypedList` would be a subclass.

Comment: ...and an unambiguous function signature: it *documents* that you're expecting more than one value. Taking in a `Variant` says nothing, you're relying on the user's knowledge that `Extend` should take an array of values, and you're not validating whether the parameter's type is actually an array. This is VBA, a `Variant` could be **anything**. I've been using a similar `List` class for quite a while now, and for me at least, the *syntactic sugar* has been much more valuable than the *possibility for hypothetical eventual extensibility*.

Comment: I disagree that it's an unneeded functionality.  Otherwise you have no way of dynamically initializing or concatenating Lists other than writing for each loops everywhere.

Comment: How about dealing with objects? Multiple types in wrapped collection? Let it blow up as well?

Comment: lets take it to second monitor.  I agree that `sequence` should be declared as something more descriptive than `Variant` but I would want it to be `Iterable` which doesn't exist in VBA.  And I am willing to take that hit for the dynamic.