# Enforcing Type with Boiler Plates

Tags: vba, type-safety

This is an implementation of Mat's [List](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32618/listt-implementation-for-vb6-vba?lq=1) using by Pseudo-inheriting my [Pythonic-List](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62963/vba-python-like-list-class?lq=1). Inheritance is not built into VBA, but it can be simulated by composing the inherited class and mimicking all it's public methods and members.  It's a PITA because a modification of a base class needs to be propagated to all sub-classes.

The implementation is simple, just add a private string data member `pTypedName`, and whenever the client code tries to add an element where `TypeName(Element) <> pTypedName` raise a type error.

## TypedList

### Private Members

```
Private this As List
Private pTypedName As String
```

### Private Methods

Type Check an element that is being added to a list.  If the type has not been set then let this element set the typename.  Otherwise, raise an error if it's not the correct type.

```
Private Sub TypeCheck(ByVal element As Variant, ByVal source As String)

    If pTypedName = vbNullString Then pTypedName = TypeName(element)
    If (TypeName(element) <> pTypedName) Then RaiseTypeError element, source

End Sub
```

Therefore

```
Dim tList as New TypedList
tList.Append "A"
```

Is valid and now `tList` is of type String.

We also want to check every element in a sequence before we let any of the elements enter the list.  If our string list is extended with `Array("a", "b", "C", 2)` we don't want any of the elements entering the list.

```
Private Sub TypeCheckSequence(ByVal sequence As Variant, ByVal source As String)

    Dim element As Variant
    For Each element In sequence
        TypeCheck element, source
    Next element

End Sub
```

The above two methods are boiler plate code at the beginning of any method that sets the data in our TypedList.

This is the error that is raised when it fails.

```
Private Sub RaiseTypeError(ByVal badItem As Variant, ByVal method As String)
    Err.Raise 13, method, "Element is of type " & TypeName(badItem) & _
                         ", not " & TypedName & "."
End Sub
```

#### Enumeration

Note we use `this.NewEnum` instead of `this.[_NewEnum]` as was in the `List` class.

```
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4

    Set NewEnum = this.NewEnum

End Property
```

### Public Methods

Client code can ask TypedList what it's type is and set the type only if the list is empty.

```
Public Property Get TypedName() As String

    TypedName = pTypedName

End Property
Public Property Let TypedName(ByVal typeName_ As String)

    If this.Count > 0 Then
        Err.Raise 9, TypeName(Me) & ".TypedName", _
            "Can only set typename of an empty list."
    End If

    pTypedName = typeName_

End Property
```

After this it's fairly boring and redundant.  I wish I wasn't required to write all of this out.

### TypeCheck Entrances

Mimic all entry points with the type checking BoilerPlate code.

#### Replacement

```
Public Property Let Item(ByVal index As Long, ByVal element As Variant)
Attribute Item.VB_UserMemId = 0

    TypeCheck element, TypeName(Me) & ".Item"
    this.Item(index) = element

End Property

Public Property Set Item(ByVal index As Long, ByVal element As Variant)
Attribute Item.VB_UserMemId = 0

    TypeCheck element, TypeName(Me) & ".Item"
    Set this.Item(index) = element

End Property

Public Property Let Slice(ByVal a As Long, ByVal b As Long, ByVal s As Integer, ByVal sequence As Variant)

    TypeCheckSequence sequence, TypeName(Me) & ".Slice"
    this.Slice(a, b, s) = sequence

End Property
```

#### Extension

```
Public Sub Append(ByVal element As Variant)

    TypeCheck element, TypeName(Me) & ".Append"
    this.Append element

End Sub

Public Sub Extend(ByVal sequence As Variant)

    TypeCheckSequence sequence, TypeName(Me) & ".Extend"
    this.Extend sequence

End Sub
```

#### Insertion

```
Public Sub Emplace(ByVal index As Long, ByVal element As Variant)

    TypeCheck element, TypeName(Me) & ".Emplace"
    this.Emplace index, element

End Sub

Public Sub Insert(ByVal index As Long, ByVal sequence As Variant)

    TypeCheckSequence sequence, TypeName(Me) & ".Insert"
    collec.Insert sequence, index

End Sub
```

### Default Interfaces

Now it's just mimic all the other methods.  Even more boring...

#### Access

```
Public Property Get Item(ByVal index As Long) As Variant
Attribute Item.VB_UserMemId = 0
    seq.Assign Item, this.Item(index)
End Property

Public Property Get Slice(ByVal a As Long, ByVal b As Long, ByVal s As Integer) As List
    Set Slice = this.Slice(a, b, s)
End Property
```

#### Removal

```
Public Sub Remove(ByVal index As Long)
    this.Remove index
End Sub

Public Sub Clear(ByVal start As Long, ByVal size As Long)
    this.Clear start, size
End Sub
```

#### Aux

```
Public Function Count() As Long
    Count = this.Count
End Function

Public Function Exists(ByVal sought As Variant) As Boolean
    Exists = this.Exists(sought)
End Function

Public Function ToString() As String
    ToString = this.ToString
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All in all I think this looks pretty good. Without proper inheritance, you're pretty much stuck with the boiler plate properties that simply call on the private untyped `List`'s properties. Everything in regards to that was done right, [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) just kinda sucks like that.

The only thing I really noticed that I didn't like was the way you're using magic numbers to raise errors.

> ```
>    Err.Raise 9, TypeName(Me) & ".TypedName", _
>         "Can only set typename of an empty list."
> ```

And

> ```
> Private Sub RaiseTypeError(ByVal badItem As Variant, ByVal method As String)
>     Err.Raise 13, method, "Element is of type " & TypeName(badItem) & _
>              ", not " & TypedName & "."
> End Sub
> ```

First, I find it in consistent to use a sub in one place, but a direct raise in another. I know you're only using error #9 in one place *now*, but pulling this out will certainly make it easier to use it elsewhere in the future.

But I mentioned the magic numbers didn't I? Normally, I would recommend defining some module scoped constants to make it clear that the code is raising a [Subscript out of Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264519(v=vs.60).aspx) and [Type Mismatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264979(v=vs.60).aspx) error (respectively), but these are built in VB errors we're raising. We're likely to use these in many places in many modules. Given that, I think it's absolutely worth the time to create a module with a public [VbErrorNumbers] Enum. It's some work, but you only ever have to do it once. In fact, I believe I'm going to do this myself later today. [A full list of built in VBA errors can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264975(v=vs.60).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can add that @RubberDuck hasn't mentioned, is that using the `this` identifier to refer to the encapsulated `List` *can* be confusing... but probably only because I have a convention to use `this` to refer to a private type that regroups an instance's private fields under a single entity; I would have called it something like `encapsulated`, or `underlying`. No biggie though.

I like that you reject an array/sequence where a single element isn't "type-safe", it's very neat.